# Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?

Tags: javascript, object, null, undefined, typeof

Why is `null` considered an `object` in JavaScript?

Is checking

```
if ( object == null )
      Do something
```

the same as

```
if ( !object )
      Do something
```

?

And also:

What is the difference between `null` and `undefined`?

Comment: Null is not an object in JavaScript! `typeof null === 'object'` but that's a bug! Here's a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxAXlJEmNMg) Watch all the videos and enjoy :)

Comment: I like to use C/C++ as the axiomatic truth for what an undefined and NULL valued variable is, since it's very straightforward.  Then see how those definitions compare to other languages' specifications.

Answer (score 1533, accepted):

```
(name is undefined)
```

**You:** What is `name`? <sup>(*)</sup>
**JavaScript:** `name`? What's a `name`? I don't know what you're talking about. You haven't ever mentioned any `name` before. Are you seeing some other scripting language on the (client-)side?

```
name = null;
```

**You:** What is `name`?
**JavaScript:** I don't know.

In short; `undefined` is where no notion of the thing exists; it has no type, and it's never been referenced before in that scope; `null` is where the thing is known to exist, but it's not known what the value is.

One thing to remember is that `null` is not, conceptually, the same as `false` or `""` or such, even if they equate after type casting, i.e.

```
name = false;
```

**You:** What is `name`?
**JavaScript:** Boolean false.

```
name = '';
```

**You:** What is `name`?
**JavaScript:** Empty string

---

<sup>*: `name` in this context is meant as a variable which has never been defined. It could be any undefined variable, however, name is a property of just about any HTML form element. It goes way, way back and was instituted well before id. It is useful because ids must be unique but names do not have to be.</sup>

Comment: But in JavaScript, the empty string '' is still a boolean false.

Comment: The empty string is not boolean false, but in the context of a conditional it is interpreted as a false(y) value (coercion).

Comment: For the second case, where name = null, instead of 'I don't know', JavaScript could answer: The null object. Other than that I like the style of the answer.

Comment: Rather than “I don't know”, I'd say the answer for `null` is “nothing”. Null is precisely defined as no value. Void, nil, nada. Nothing.

Comment: Love that style of answering. In general, *"You haven't ever mentioned any* `name` *before"* is true. However, declaring a variable without assigning a value to it (`var somevar;`), will surprisingly enough still result in `undefined`.

Comment: @MC Emperor - also, you can explicitly set a declared variable to `undefined`, so I agree that the _"You haven't ever mentioned any `name` before"_ is a bit misleading.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of: "Is (object == null) the same as (!object)"

Comment: I always thought undefined was same as a null. But now I realized undefined is almost like null of a null.

Comment: >Are you seeing some other scripting language on the (client-)side?
Hahahaha

Comment: @MC Emperor - It's not really surprising when you consider the difference between de_clare_ and de_fine_. `var somevar` is a variable declaration (a reserved area in memory) whereas `var somevar = 'foo'` is a variable assignment or definition, if you will. If you attempt to reference the value of "somevar", javascript has reserved space and hence knows the variable exists, but since no assignment has been made, javascript lets you know "somevar" exists as nothing more than a declaration by returning "undefined". That's really the only sensible thing it can return.

Comment: Tested this on Chrome console and noticed the following: Initialize `var name = null;`. First test: `name == null; // => false` Second test: `name == 'null'; // => true`. This is true since `typeof(name) = 'string'`. The variable `name` is implicitly a string. What a subtlety!

Comment: @AndreasGrech: [false] is not actually [""], if you put === between the two

Comment: @antmary Indeed, and that's because `===` does not do type coercion.

Comment: I believe you're explanation is not entirely correct (however I could be wrong as well). Undefined is the value which should be used when no value is known. `car is undefined` means that Javascript doesn't know the *value* of car, it does know however what car is. Null represents the absence of a value, there is no relevant value. `car = null` means that there simply is no car. So what you've defined as null is actually undefined, and null is something completely different.

Comment: @AndreasGrech In Javascript, the empty string is not a Boolean false. It simply evaluates to Boolean false when you use coercion.

Comment: Love the story telling approach :D

Comment: typeof is asking JavaScript for the type of thing the value of a variable is, not for the variable itself. When no variable is ever declared, JavaScript throws a reference error. That should be the first line in your dialog where JS hasn't heard of any 'name' you speak of. If you declare a variable, but don't assign a value or if you assign undefined then that means the thing exists, it just doesn't have a value, therefore the type of that value is undefined. Null on the other hand causes problems. Null is supposed to mean 'no value' but if you ask for `typeof null` you get 'object' WAT.

Comment: I would like to agree with Tiddo and suggest that the cause of a value being `undefined` is ambiguous whereas `null` is like saying "this space intentionally left blank".

Comment: [`name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a part protected (it can be only a string) property of window.

Comment: There is no `is` keyword in JavaScript/ECMAScript, much less an operator, is it? I am referring to the `(name is undefined)` expression.

Comment: This answer is misleading to the point of being incorrect. I have written a referenced answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009911/38522).

Comment: @AndreasGrech In refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined#comment2274178_802371): No, it is not. It is falsy, but not boolean.

Comment: null should have never been an object

Comment: I agree with @BenAston that this answer, although accepted with many upvotes, is wrong and misleading. OP should un-accept this answer and accept Ben's instead.

Answer (score 148):

The difference can be summarized into this snippet:

```
alert(typeof(null));      // object
alert(typeof(undefined)); // undefined

alert(null !== undefined) //true
alert(null == undefined)  //true
```

Checking

`object == null` is different to check `if ( !object )`.

The latter is equal to `! Boolean(object)`, because the unary `!` operator automatically cast the right operand into a Boolean.

Since `Boolean(null)` equals false then `!false === true`.

So if your object is **not null**, *but* **false** or **0** or **""**, the check will pass
because:

```
alert(Boolean(null)) //false
alert(Boolean(0))    //false
alert(Boolean(""))   //false
```

Comment: @kentaromiura For us Javascript noobs...maybe only me...what is this Boolean(value) syntax? Casting to a Boolean?

Comment: @xr280xr Yes, it's casting. Try `String(null)` to see another example of casting. You can even do silly things like `Number(null + 2)`... but you shouldn't :-). Excellent answer from kentaromiura.

Comment: Remember `typeof` is an operator. You wouldn't wrap the operand in parenthesis for the same reason you wouldn't write `var sum = 1 +(1);`.

Answer (score 141):

`null` is [not an object](http://www.2ality.com/2011/03/javascript-values-not-everything-is.html), it is a *primitive value*. For example, you cannot add properties to it. Sometimes people wrongly assume that it is an object, because `typeof null` returns `"object"`. But that is actually a bug (that might even be fixed in ECMAScript 6).

The difference between `null` and `undefined` is as follows:

- `undefined`: used by JavaScript and means “no value”. Uninitialized variables, missing parameters and unknown variables have that value.

  ```
  > var noValueYet;
  > console.log(noValueYet);
  undefined

  > function foo(x) { console.log(x) }
  > foo()
  undefined

  > var obj = {};
  > console.log(obj.unknownProperty)
  undefined
  ```

  Accessing unknown variables, however, produces an exception:

  ```
  > unknownVariable
  ReferenceError: unknownVariable is not defined
  ```
- `null`: used by programmers to indicate “no value”, e.g. as a parameter to a function.

Examining a variable:

```
console.log(typeof unknownVariable === "undefined"); // true

var foo;
console.log(typeof foo === "undefined"); // true
console.log(foo === undefined); // true

var bar = null;
console.log(bar === null); // true
```

As a general rule, you should always use === and never == in JavaScript (== performs [all kinds of conversions](http://www.2ality.com/2011/06/javascript-equality.html) that can produce unexpected results). The check `x == null` is an edge case, because it works for both `null` and `undefined`:

```
> null == null
true
> undefined == null
true
```

A common way of checking whether a variable has a value is to convert it to boolean and see whether it is `true`. That conversion is performed by the `if` statement and the boolean operator ! (“not”).

```
function foo(param) {
    if (param) {
        // ...
    }
}
function foo(param) {
    if (! param) param = "abc";
}
function foo(param) {
    // || returns first operand that can't be converted to false
    param = param || "abc";
}
```

Drawback of this approach: All of the following values evaluate to `false`, so you have to be careful (e.g., the above checks can’t distinguish between `undefined` and `0`).

- `undefined`, `null`
- Booleans: `false`
- Numbers: `+0`, `-0`, `NaN`
- Strings: `""`

You can test the conversion to boolean by using `Boolean` as a function (normally it is a constructor, to be used with `new`):

```
> Boolean(null)
false
> Boolean("")
false
> Boolean(3-3)
false
> Boolean({})
true
> Boolean([])
true
```

Comment: Why reference `+0` and `-0` seperately if `+0 === -0` ?

Comment: Probably because you can still distinguish `+0` and `-0`: `1/+0 !== 1/-0`.

Comment: This answer links to a post that links back to this answer as source... probably meant to link to this instead http://www.2ality.com/2013/10/typeof-null.html

Comment: Oh right, like in C, where uninitialized variable declarations are considered undefined (old versions could actually contain a previous programs data).

Comment: Programmers can also use `undefined` to indicate "no value", and JS can also use `null` to indicate "no value".

Comment: @Axel Raoschmayer 
I don't blame you. Netscape programmers, had it wrong all the way until very recently. I believe it was corrected in Firefox 5 or later.
They didn't know that null is a supplement for a missing property;method;object-reference, whereas undefined: a missing value. Undefined is typeles, null is not.

null reflects an undefined object
undefined an undefined primitive.
That's why when typecasting, only null == undefined > true, but no other falsy primitives or objects . That's because when you take away the type from null - what remains is a naked undefined.

Comment: "But that is actually a bug (that might even be fixed in ECMAScript 6)" – source?

Comment: I think @neo is the one.

Comment: It won't ever be fixed. If it gets fixed all the internet could break down. It's the same problem of NaN === NaN

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a deliberate choice (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009911/38522)). `NaN !== NaN` is also not a bug (and also nothing to do with JS).

Answer (score 28):

> What is the difference between null and undefined??

A property when it has no definition is `undefined`. a `null` is an object. Its type is `object`. null is a special value meaning "no value. undefined is not an object, its type is undefined.

You can declare a variable, set it to null, and the behavior is identical except that you'll see "null" printed out versus "undefined". You can even compare a variable that is undefined to null or vice versa, and the condition will be true:

```
 undefined == null
 null == undefined
```

Refer to [JavaScript Difference between null and undefined](https://www.google.nl/search?q=JavaScript+Difference+between+null+and+undefined&gws_rd=cr&ei=lM1MWYjDOs_OwAL-_KioDg) for more detail.

and with your new **edit** **yes**

```
if (object == null)  does mean the same  if(!object)
```

when testing if `object` is false, they both only meet the condition when testing if **false**, but not when true

Check here: [Javascript gotcha](http://blog.kodekabuki.com/post/30056940/javascript-gotcha-undefined-vs-null)

Comment: You should use ===, then undefined !== null :D

Comment: pay attention to the last part, is incorrect
see my answer ;)

Comment: !object is not the same as "object == null" ... In fact, they're quite different. !object will return true if is object is 0, an empty string, Boolean false, undefined or null.

Comment: Is null really an object? The 1st link you have provided checks null by typeof, but typeof(null) evaluates to 'object' because of an language design error.

Comment: @TStamper: Is the web-site for that 'Javascript gotcha' (http://blog.poundbang.in/post/30056940/javascript-gotcha-undefined-vs-null) taken down? I see a 404 there ...

Comment: `null` is not an object. That `typeof null == 'object';` returns true is because of a bug that can't be fixed in JavaScript (presently, but may change in the future).

Answer (score 22):

First part of the question:

> Why is null considered an object in JavaScript?

It is a JavaScript design error they can't fix now. It should have been type null, not type object, or not have it at all. It necessitates an extra check (sometimes forgotten) when detecting real objects and is source of bugs.

Second part of the question:

> Is checking 
>   
>   `if (object == null)` 
>   `Do something` 
>   
>   the same as 
>   
>   `if (!object)` 
>   `Do something`

The two checks are always both false except for:

- object is undefined or null: both true.
- object is primitive, and 0, `""`, or false:  first check false, second true.

If the object is not a primitive, but a real Object, like `new Number(0)`, `new String("")`, or `new Boolean(false)`, then both checks are false.

So if 'object' is interpreted to mean a real Object then both checks are always the same. If primitives are allowed then the checks are different for 0, `""`, and false.

In cases like `object==null`, the unobvious results could be a source of bugs. Use of `==` is not recommended ever, use `===` instead.

Third part of the question:

> And also: 
>   
>   What is the difference between null and undefined?

In JavaScript, one difference is that null is of type object and undefined is of type undefined.

In JavaScript, `null==undefined` is true, and considered equal if type is ignored. Why they decided that, but 0, `""` and false aren't equal, I don't know. It seems to be an arbitrary opinion.

In JavaScript, `null===undefined` is not true since the type must be the same in `===`.

In reality, null and undefined are identical, since they both represent non-existence. So do 0, and `""` for that matter too, and maybe the empty containers `[]` and `{}`. So many types of the same nothing are a recipe for bugs. One type or none at all is better. I would try to use as few as possible.

'false', 'true', and '!' are another bag of worms that could be simplified, for example, `if(!x)` and `if(x)` alone are sufficient, you don't need true and false.

A declared `var x` is type undefined if no value is given, but it should be the same as if x was never declared at all. Another bug source is an empty nothing container. So it is best to declare and define it together, like `var x=1`.

People are going round and round in circles trying to figure out all these various types of nothing, but it's all just the same thing in complicated different clothes. The reality is

```
undefined===undeclared===null===0===""===[]==={}===nothing
```

And maybe all should throw exceptions.

Comment: Great answer, but it goes a little too far with []: "_In reality, null and undefined are identical... and maybe the empty containers [] and {}._"  You could probably talk me into thinking {} should be some flavor of null, but my gut impression is that it shouldn't. But less controversially, **an empty array `[]` understandably has a `.push()` function**, so there's no good argument for [] being null. $0.02.

Comment: Thanks. I feel like this answers the original question better than the chosen answer. I'm hoping can anyone elaborate on "It is a JavaScript design error they can't fix now" and link to docs explaining exactly why javascript acts this way?

Comment: It's not a design error (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64009911/38522)).

Answer (score 15):

**TLDR**

`undefined` is a primitive value in JavaScript that indicates the implicit absence of a value. Uninitialized variables automatically have this value, and functions without an explicit `return` statement, return `undefined`.

`null` is also a primitive value in JavaScript. It indicates [the intentional absence of an object value](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-null-value). `null` in JavaScript was designed to enable interoperability with [Java](https://www.java.com/).

`typeof null` returns `"object"` because of a peculiarity in the design of the language, stemming from the demand that JavaScript be interoperable with Java. It does not mean `null` is an instance of an object. It means: given the tree of primitive types in JavaScript, `null` is part of the "object-type primitive" subtree. This is explained more fully below.

**Details**

`undefined` is a primitive value that [represents](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-undefined-value) the implicit absence of a value. Note that `undefined` was not directly accessible until [JavaScript 1.3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.3) in 1998. This tells us that `null` was intended to be the value used by programmers when explicitly indicating the absence of a value. Uninitialized variables automatically have the value `undefined`. `undefined` is a [one-of-a-kind type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-undefined-type) in the ECMAScript specification.

`null` is a primitive value that [represents](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-null-value) the intentional absence of an object value. `null` is also a [one-of-a-kind type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-terms-and-definitions-null-type) in the ECMAScript specification.

`null` in JavaScript was designed with a view to enable interoperability with [Java](https://www.java.com/), [both from a "look" perspective, and from a programmatic perspective (eg the LiveConnect Java/JS bridge planned for 1996)](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/1271954691421691905?s=20). Both Brendan Eich and others have since expressed distaste at the inclusion of *two* "absence of value" values, but in 1995 Eich was [under orders](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/1271993445180010496?s=20) to "make [JavaScript] look like Java".

[Brendan Eich](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/1271998084642246657?s=20):

> If I didn't have "Make it look like Java" as an order from management,
> *and* I had more time (hard to unconfound these two causal factors), then I would have preferred a Self-like "everything's an object"
> approach: no Boolean, Number, String wrappers. No undefined and null.
> Sigh.

In order to accommodate Java's concept of `null` which, due to the strongly-typed nature of Java, can only be assigned to variables typed to a reference type (rather primitives), Eich chose to position the special `null` value at the top of the object prototype chain (i.e. the top of the reference types), and to include the `null` type as part of the set of "object-type primitives".

The `typeof` operator was added shortly thereafter [in JavaScript 1.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.1), released on 19th August 1996.

From [the V8 blog](https://v8.dev/blog/react-cliff):

> `typeof null` returns `object`, and not `null`, despite `null` being a
> type of its own. To understand why, consider that the set of all
> JavaScript types is divided into two groups:
>
> 1. objects (i.e. the Object type)
> 2. primitives (i.e. any non-object value)
>
> As such, `null` means “no object value”, whereas `undefined` means “no
> value”.

> [image]

> Following this line of thought, Brendan Eich designed JavaScript to
> make `typeof` return 'object' for all values on the right-hand side,
> i.e. all objects and null values, in the spirit of Java. That’s why
> `typeof null === 'object'` despite the spec having a separate `null` type.

> [image]

So Eich designed the hierarchy of primitive types to enable interoperability with Java. This led to him positioning `null` along with the "object-type primitives" on the hierarchy. To reflect this, when `typeof` was added to the language shortly thereafter, he chose `typeof null` to return `"object"`.

The surprise expressed by JavaScript developers at `typeof null === "object"` is the result of an impedance mismatch (or abstraction leak) between a weakly-typed language (JavaScript) that has both `null` and `undefined`, and another, strongly-typed language (Java) that only has `null`, and in which `null` is [strictly defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) to refer to a reference type (not a primitive type).

**Note that this is all logical, reasonable and defensible. `typeof null === "object"` is not a bug, but a second-order effect of having to accommodate Java interoperability.**

A number of imperfect backwards rationalisations and/or conventions have emerged, including that `undefined` indicates *implicit* absence of a value, and that `null` indicates *intentional* absence of a value; or that `undefined` is the absence of a value, and `null` is specifically the absence of an *object* value.

A relevant conversation with Brendan Eich, screenshotted for posterity:

[image]

Comment: yes undefinded means the variable was declared but not initialized to any value or refrence of an object. var x; //now x's value is undefined in practice COMPARE TO var x; x = null; //now x's value is null. Null is just a silly type of object like numbers and strings, which can be used as a placeholder. Undefined means it was not initialized to any value

Answer (score 12):

```
typeof null;      // object
typeof undefined; // undefined
```

The value null represents the intentional absence of any object value. It is one of JavaScript's primitive values and is treated as falsy for boolean operations.

```
var x = null;
var y;
```

x is declared & defined as null

y is declared but not defined. It is declared with no value so it is undefined.

z is not declared so would also be undefined if you attempted to use z.

Comment: This answer conflates undeclared with `undefined`.

Answer (score 9):

One way to make sense of null and undefined is to understand where each occurs.

Expect a null return value in the following situations:

- Methods that query the DOM

  ```
  console.log(window.document.getElementById("nonExistentElement"));
  //Prints: null
  ```
- JSON responses received from an Ajax request

```
    {
      name: "Bob",
      address: null
    }
```

- [RegEx.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).
- New functionality that is in a state of flux. The following returns null:

```
        var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf({}));

       // But this returns undefined:

        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor({}, "a");
```

All other cases of non-existence are denoted by undefined (as noted by @Axel). Each of the following prints "undefined":

```
    var uninitalised;
    console.log(uninitalised);

    var obj = {};
    console.log(obj.nonExistent);

    function missingParam(missing){
        console.log(missing);
    }

    missingParam();

    var arr = [];
    console.log(arr.pop());
```

Of course if you decide to write var unitialised = null; or return null from a method yourself then you have null occurring in other situations. But that should be pretty obvious.

A third case is when you want to access a variable but you don't even know if it has been declared. For that case use typeof to avoid a reference error:

```
if(typeof unknown !== "undefined"){
    //use unknown
}
```

In summary check for null when you are manipulating the DOM, dealing with Ajax, or using certain ECMAScript 5 features. For all other cases it is safe to check for undefined with strict equality:

```
if(value === undefined){
  // stuff
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Comparison of many different null checks in JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/aaronhoffman/DdRHB/5/

```
// Variables to test
var myNull = null;
var myObject = {};
var myStringEmpty = "";
var myStringWhiteSpace = " ";
var myStringHello = "hello";
var myIntZero = 0;
var myIntOne = 1;
var myBoolTrue = true;
var myBoolFalse = false;
var myUndefined;

...trim...
```

http://aaron-hoffman.blogspot.com/2013/04/javascript-null-checking-undefined-and.html

[image: JavaScript Null Check Comparison Chart]

Comment: does "var myUndefined;" define the variable (as a known variable with unknown type)?

Answer (score 6):

To add to the answer of *What is the differrence between `undefined` and `null`*, from [JavaScript Definitive Guide 6th Edition, p.41 on this page](http://books.google.com/books?id=6TAODdEIxrgC&lpg=PA41&ots=obbpJPKzZH&dq=null%20undefined&pg=PA41#v=onepage&q=null%20undefined&f=false):

> You might consider `undefined` to represent system-level, unexpected,
>   or error-like absense of value and `null` to represent program-level,
>   normal, or expected absence of value.  If you need to assign one of
>   these values to a variable or property or pass one of these values to
>   a function, `null` is almost always the right choice.

Answer (score 5):

null and undefined are both false for value equality (null==undefined): they both collapse to boolean false. They are not the same object (null!==undefined).

undefined is a property of the global object ("window" in browsers), but is a primitive type and not an object itself. It's the default value for uninitialized variables and functions ending without a return statement.

null is an instance of Object. null is used for DOM methods that return collection objects to indicate an empty result, which provides a false value without indicating an error.

Comment: `null` is not an instance of `Object`.

Answer (score 5):

Some precisions:

null and undefined *are* two different values. One is representing the absence of a value for a name and the other is representing the absence of a name.

---

What happens in an `if` goes as follows for `if( o )`:

The expression in the parentheses o is evaluated, and then the `if` kicks in type-coercing the value of the expression in the parentheses - in our case `o`.

Falsy (that will get coerced to false) values in JavaScript are: *'', null, undefined, 0, and false*.

Answer (score 2):

For example `window.someWeirdProperty` is undefined, so

`"window.someWeirdProperty === null"` evaluates to false while

`"window.someWeirdProperty === undefined"` evaluates to true.

Moreover checkif `if (!o)` is not the same as checking `if (o == null)` for `o` being `false`.

Comment: Can you elaborate the difference between the two conditions

Comment: read my answer, he means that if o is equals to 0, false or "" 
the Boolean value is false:

var undef, various =[0,"",null,false,undef];
for(var obj in various){
 alert(!obj); //4 times false in IE,5 in FF ;)
}

Answer (score 2):

The following function shows why and is capable for working out the difference:

```
function test() {
        var myObj = {};
        console.log(myObj.myProperty);
        myObj.myProperty = null;
        console.log(myObj.myProperty);
}
```

If you call

```
test();
```

You're getting

> undefined
>
> null

The first `console.log(...)` tries to get `myProperty` from `myObj` while it is not yet defined - so it gets back "undefined". After assigning null to it, the second `console.log(...)` returns obviously "null" because `myProperty` exists, but it has the value `null` assigned to it.

In order to be able to query this difference, JavaScript has `null` and `undefined`: While `null` is - just like in other languages an object, `undefined` cannot be an object because there is no instance (even not a `null` instance) available.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:

```
   <script>
function f(a){
  alert(typeof(a));
  if (a==null) alert('null');
  a?alert(true):alert(false);
}
</script>
                                          //return:
<button onclick="f()">nothing</button>    //undefined    null    false
<button onclick="f(null)">null</button>   //object       null    false
<button onclick="f('')">empty</button>    //string               false
<button onclick="f(0)">zero</button>      //number               false
<button onclick="f(1)">int</button>       //number               true
<button onclick="f('x')">str</button>     //string               true
```

Answer (score 1):

From "The Principles of Object-Oriented Javascript" by Nicholas C. Zakas

> But why an object when the type is null? (In fact, this has been acknowledged as an error by TC39, the committee that designs and maintains JavaScript. You could reason that null is an empty object pointer, making "object" a logical return value, but that’s still confusing.)

Zakas, Nicholas C. (2014-02-07). The Principles of Object-Oriented JavaScript (Kindle Locations 226-227). No Starch Press. Kindle Edition.

That said:

```
var game = null; //typeof(game) is "object"

game.score = 100;//null is not an object, what the heck!?
game instanceof Object; //false, so it's not an instance but it's type is object
//let's make this primitive variable an object;
game = {}; 
typeof(game);//it is an object
game instanceof Object; //true, yay!!!
game.score = 100;
```

Undefined case:

```
var score; //at this point 'score' is undefined
typeof(score); //'undefined'
var score.player = "felix"; //'undefined' is not an object
score instanceof Object; //false, oh I already knew that.
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to think about 'null' is to recall how the similar concept is used in databases, where it indicates that a field contains "no value at all."

- Yes, the item's value is known; it *is* 'defined.' It *has* been initialized.
- The item's value is: *"there is no value."*

This is a very useful technique for writing programs that are more-easily debugged.  An 'undefined' variable might be the result of a bug ... *(how would you know?)* ... but if the variable contains the value 'null,' you know that "someone, somewhere in this program, *set it* to 'null.'"  Therefore, I suggest that, when you need to get rid of the value of a variable, don't "delete" ... set it to 'null.'  The old value will be orphaned and soon will be garbage-collected; the new value is, "there is no value (now)."  In both cases, the variable's state is certain: "it obviously, deliberately, got that way."

Answer (score 1):

The other fun thing about null, compared to undefined, is that it can be incremented.

```js
x = undefined
x++
y = null
y++
console.log(x) // NaN
console.log(y) // 0
```

This is useful for setting default numerical values for counters. How many times have you set a variable to -1 in its declaration?

Answer (score 1):

1. Undefined means a variable has been declared but it has not been assigned any value while Null can be assigned to a variable representing "no value".(Null is an assignment operator)

2.Undefined is a type itself while Null is an object.

3.Javascript can itself initialize any unassigned variable to undefined but it can never set value of a variable to null. This has to be done programatically.

Answer (score 1):

In **Javascript** `null` is not an `object` type it is a `primitave` type.

**What is the difference?**
**Undefined** refers to a pointer that has not been set.
**Null** refers to the null pointer for example something has manually set a variable to be of type `null`

Answer (score 1):

**What is a type?**

A type is a way to categorize *values*. Here is a table with the types in question and their `typeof` result.

| Type | Values type contains | `typeof` result | Is `typeof` result a lie? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Undefined | Only: `undefined` | `"undefined"` | No |
| Null | Only: `null` | `"object"` | Yes |
| Object | Infinite amount of values: `{}`, `{a: "b"}`, ... | `"object"` | No |

`null` is **not** an object, its a value of type Null.

The `typeof` operator is **lying**! It returning `"object"` for `null` is a mistake in the JavaScript language.

I wrote a chapter about this in my open-source e-book. You can read it here https://github.com/carltheperson/advanced-js-objects

Answer (score 0):

`null` is an object. Its type is null. `undefined` is not an object; its type is undefined.

Comment: wrong - both `null` and `undefined` are primitive values - `typeof null === 'object'` is a language bug, because `Object(null) !== null`

Comment: No, is not. Object() cast work in that way, see http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf

--
15.2.2.1 new Object ( [ value ] )

...

8. (The argument value was not supplied or its type was Null or Undefined.)
Create a new native ECMAScript object.
The [[Prototype]] property of the newly constructed object is set to the Object prototype object.
The [[Class]] property of the newly constructed object is set to "Object".
The newly constructed object has no [[Value]] property.
Return the newly created native object.

Comment: @Christoph:
I mean, you're right.
null *should* be a type, what I means is that you cannot check it in that way because: 
alert(new Object() !== new Object()); /* true, new istance is not the same istance */

alert(Object(null).constructor == {}.constructor); /* true as in spec */
alert(Object(null).prototype == {}.prototype); /* true as in spec */

alert(null instanceof Object); /* obviously false, null means not instantiated */
But basically is a spec bug XD
see:
http://www.uselesspickles.com/blog/2006/06/12/javascript-null-identity-crisis/
and 
http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html

Answer (score 0):

Use null to define something as having no value, use undefined when you expect something might not be defined at all.

For example, if a variable has no value, assign it as null.

```
var weDontHaveAValue = null;
```

If you expect that something might be not defined at all, e.g. an optional options argument, use undefined.

```
if (typeof args.optionalParam !== 'undefined') { }
```

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between null and undefined is that null represents
a missing object, while undefined represents an uninitialized state of a variable.

You can think of null as an undefined object but undefined will be undefined only
since its type is undefined.

```
let a; 
console.log(a); //undefined, since it is declared but not initialized

console.log(null == undefined) //true
console.log(null === undefined) // false

console.log(typeof null) //object
console.log(typeof undefined) //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: console]

**Not defined** and **undefined** are not the same thing happening.

```js
age;
```

You: What is the value of `age`?

Computer: Okay, let me check my memory/reference table..... at this point (the time of you asking), i do not see any identifier named `age`, not in this scope/context or any parent scope/context; `age` is not known to me. Maybe later i will come across an instruction to add that identifier to memory, but it does not exist right now.

```js
var age;
```

You: What is the value of `age`;

Computer: Okay, checking my memory... I see an identifier in my reference table with that name `age` but no value or pointer or anything was assigned to it at the time i added it, so i don't know; you can consider it (`age`) empty/nothing/useless.

```js
var age = null;
```

You: What is the value of `age`;

Computer: Okay, checking my memory... i see `age` in my reference table: it is null. Basically, it is nothing/empty, you cannot do anything with this value; this was intentional.

Now, i probably should not explain it this way but hopefully it will make  sense.

I can see why null was designed to be an object in JS, and i personally like it that way.

`null` and `undefined` **practically** means the same thing: empty/nothing. The difference is in how it is used conceptually.

I look at `null` as developer-intended nothingness; something being null was done on purpose to represent nothing. I look at undefined as computer-intended nothingness; something not having value by accident of the developer/user.

For example, if you call a function from a library/sdk and got back null, you can almost be sure that was designed on purpose by the developer/author; they specifically wanted to indicate nothingness.

Also see - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null