# When JavaScript returns null & undefined?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

I have been using JavaScript for couple of years and never cared about the difference between `null` & `undefined` earlier, I always use `undefined` to validate the object existence.

But recently I came through [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript). Here they said

> JavaScript distinguishes between null, which is an object of type 'object' that indicates a deliberate non-value, and undefined, which is an object of type 'undefined' that indicates an uninitialized value — that is, a value hasn't even been assigned yet. We'll talk about variables later, but in JavaScript it is possible to declare a variable without assigning a value to it. If you do this, the variable's type is undefined.

I am completely confused now, what exactly is non-value here. How this non-value differs from `undefined`. And what are the circumstances javascript returns `null`.

I have tried the below sample

```
var sam;
alert(sam);  // returns undefined
```

And

```
try {
    //var sam;
    alert(sam);  
} catch(ex) { }   // exception says: sam is undefined
```

And I am not sure about when js returning nulls. Can someone clarify me.

Comment: Here is an article describing the differences: [http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html](http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html) Just so people don't miss the videos linked in the article: [Videos of Douglas Crockford posted on Yahoo](http://video.yahoo.com/watch/111593)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript

Comment: thanks phoenix for the link.. it helps me understand the differences.. but can u share me a code sample javascript returns null...?? because i coulndt able to find out when it returns null..

Comment: See what happens if you set undefined = 'something' ;)

Comment: This article covers it nicely:
http://andrewgrant.net.au/2012/01/04/javascript-%e2%80%93-undefined-versus-null/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> alert(sam);     // returns undefined

Nope, that's an exception.

You get `undefined` when you access an unset property; you get an error when you use an unset name directly.

Global variables are interesting because they can be accessed either using a simple variable name, or by using properties of the `window` global object:

```
alert(window.sam);      // undefined
alert(window['sam']);   // undefined
alert('sam' in window); // false
alert(sam);             // ERROR
```

If `sam` is declared but not initialised, accessing `window.sam` still gets you `undefined`, but for a different reason: there is an entry in the `window` object for `sam`, but it points to the same `undefined` object as you get when you access a non-existant property.

```
var sam;
alert(window.sam);      // undefined
alert(window['sam']);   // undefined
alert('sam' in window); // ** true
alert(sam);             // ** undefined
```

This is of course a confusing bloody mess; `undefined` is one of the worst mistakes in the design of the JavaScript language.

`null` on the other hand is fine and works pretty much the same as null/nil/void/None values in other languages. It doesn't come into any of the above.

Comment: thanks for the response bobince... as i understand js never returns null in anytime unless we set variable=null... am i right..

Comment: Yep. `null` is a normal value that doesn't show up unless you specifically ask for it. `undefined` is the only one that magically pops up out of nowhere thanks to the language itself. (Care, though: with the normal double-equals comparator, `undefined==null`.)

Comment: "but it points to the same `undefined` object"? Surely, you meant to say — has the same `undefined` value.

Comment: undefined is not of type "object"
`typeof undefined` = `"undefined"`
it's only null that is of type "object"
`typeof null` = `"object"`

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// variable with an unasigned value
var a;
if (a == undefined) {
  alert('a is undefined');
}

if (a == null) {
  alert('a is undefined');
}

// this will produce an error
if (b == undefined) {
  alert('b is undefined');
}

// this is the right way to handle not defined variables
if (typeof(c) == 'undefined') {
  alert('c is blabla');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a variable to receive a null value it must be assigned.  `null` is used to indicate an unknown or don't care value.  `undefined` on the other hand is designed to indicate that the propery being accessed has never ben assigned a value.  This differs from `null`.

With `null` one is deliberately saying "I don't know what value this should have yet" or "I don't care what value this is right now".  OTH in `undefined` is really saying "Are you sure you should be using this value it hasn't been assigned".

Comment: thanks Anthony.. this is wat i have expected.. so js never returns null in anytime unless we set variable=null.. am i right..??

Comment: @Remesh: your use of the word "returns" is a little confusing. Functions "return" values.  I think what you mean to establish is that given that a variable has never been assigned a value it could never have the value of null.  That is correct.

Comment: if we have not intialized a variable, js assigns (returns) undefined   .. same way when the object is nulled by javascript,, as i know it would only be assigned explicitly by var=null;

Answer (score 1):

The way I distinguish them is undefined being "I have not defined this value," and null being "I have defined this value, but I do not know or cannot figure out what the value should be."