# how to check for null and non-number data enterd(like characters or special char)in to text box by using java script?

Tags: javascript

hi i have a page having text box. in that i should not allow user to go to next page unless he enters some *NUMBER*. it should number but not text and  should not be empty , any help pls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
isNaN(yourText.value)
```

return true if its `Not a Number`

Answer (score 0):

The title references checking for null, so you might also want to look at [the null object in javascript.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript)