# How do I pass null to a nullable parameter of a ASP.NET web service method via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, nullable

Given the following ASP.NET code:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class Quotes : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public void Calculate(int param1, int? param2)
    {
```

etc..  How can I pass a null value to param2?  If I don't pass the parameter at all, or I pass undefined, my error handler fires with `"Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'param2'`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I was being stupid.  I simply pass null!

[Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using C# 4.0 you could set a default value on the parameter.

ie

```
[WebMethod]
    public void Calculate(int param1, int? param2 = null)
    {...}
```