# Is null an object?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Null object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript)

Null is an object right? So if i set x to null, why can't i get the constructor value?

```
 var x = null;
 alert(typeof x);
 alert(x.constructor);
```

Comment: also a possible duplicate of <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662952/is-null-an-object-in-javascript">Is null an object in JavaScript?</a>

Comment: @birryree, it's not a duplicate of that topic. That one is about the difference between `null` and `undefined`, while this is about the question if `null` itself is an object.

Answer (score 10):

`null` in JS is a primitive value. It wasn't constructed by any constructor function, so it doesn't have a `constructor` property. `typeof null` being `'object'` is basically a horrible lie retained for historical reasons. Don't expect too much consistency from JS, you'll be disappointed!

Primitive values can often behave like objects in JS due to autoboxing: `(1).constructor` works despite `1` also being a primitive value, because it implicitly calls `new Number(1)`. But there is no Object form of `null` (or `undefined`) to automatically convert to, so in this case you get an error.

In general you should avoid using `constructor`. For many class/instance models built on top of JS it doesn't do what you think at all. `instanceof` typically works better.

Comment: "Don't expect too much consistency from JS..." This needs to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Null is not an object in Javascript - null is the singular instance of the `null` primitive type, and as such has no constructor.

Comment: Yep, but there's only one of it, and only nothing can be nothing - nothing else can be nothing, and if you make anything something it's not nothing anymore.