# Why does `typeof this` return "object"?

Tags: javascript, call, ecma262

```
var f = function(o){ return this+":"+o+"::"+(typeof this)+":"+(typeof o) };
f.call( "2", "2" );
// "2:2::object:string"

var f = function(o){ return this+":"+(typeof this)+":"+(typeof o); };
var x = [1,/foo/,"bar",function(){},true,[],{}];
for (var i=0;i<x.length;++i) console.log(f.call(x[i],x[i]));
// "1:object:number"
// "/foo/:object:object"
// "bar:object:string"
// "function () {\n}:function:function"
// "true:object:boolean"
// ":object:object"
// "[object Object]:object:object"
```

I see the same results in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, so I assume it's per [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf), but...why? And where in the spec is this defined? And why not for functions?

Comment: wow, never knew that.  now I wonder why that is as well!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As defined in ECMA-262 ECMAScript Language Specification 3rd edition (see footnote), It's based on [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (Section 15.3.4.4):

```
var result = fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]]);
```

## Parameters

`thisArg`

> Determines the value of this inside
>   fun. If thisArg is null or undefined,
>   this will be the global object.
>   Otherwise, this will be equal to
>   Object(thisArg) (which is thisArg if
>   thisArg is already an object, or a
>   String, Boolean, or Number if thisArg
>   is a primitive value of the
>   corresponding type). Therefore, it is
>   always true that typeof this ==
>   "object" when the function executes.

Note in particular the last line.

The crucial thing is that js primitives (`string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null`, `undefined`) are immutable, so a function can not be attached to them. Therefore the `call` function wraps the primitive in an `Object` so that the function can be attached.

E.g.:

Doesn't work:

```
var test = "string";
//the next 2 lines are invalid, as `test` is a primitive 
test.someFun = function () { alert(this); }; 
test.someFun();
```

Works:

```
var test = "string";
//wrap test up to give it a mutable wrapper
var temp = Object(test);
temp.someFun = function () { alert(this); };
temp.someFun();
```

(footnote) - as [patrick dw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw) noted in the comments, this will change in [ECMA-262 ECMAScript Language Specification 5th edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) when in strict mode:

> From Section 15.3.4.4:
>
> > NOTE The
> >     thisArg value is passed without
> >     modification as the this value. This
> >     is a change from Edition 3, where a
> >     undefined or null thisArg is replaced
> >     with the global object and ToObject is
> >     applied to all other values and that
> >     result is passed as the this value.

Comment: Note that this changes as of ECMAScript 5. From Section 15.3.4.4: *NOTE The thisArg value is passed without modification as the this value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a undefined or null thisArg is replaced with the global object and ToObject is applied to all other values and that result is passed as the this value.*

Comment: Ah ha, that puts us on the correct track in the ECMAScript-262 rev3 spec. Section 15.3.4.4 says "If _thisArg_ is **null** or **undefined**, the called function is passed the global object as the **this** value. Otherwise, the called function is passed `ToObject(thisArg)` as the **this** value." The `ToObject` operator is described in section 9.9. Basically using `call` with a number is like passing `new Number(42)`, for which `typeof` yields `"object"`. Thanks!

Comment: @patrickdw Excellent news on the change, thanks for the note!

Comment: @Phrogz - You're welcome. I should also note that the new behavior applies to the new "strict" mode. Otherwise, the original behavior will be applied. This is detailed in *Section 10.4.3 Entering Function Code*.

Comment: @patrick dw good clarification, I've added your note to the answer.