# Sort table by two columns vanilla js

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table

How can i sort my table by two columns ( Name, Available) on page load? I can use vanilla js

```
        <table class="table_sort">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="sorted-asc">Name</th>
        <th>Genre</th>
        <th>Publish year</th>
        <th>Quanity</th>
        <th class="available">Available</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tbody">
    <tr>
        <td>aname1</td>

        <td>genre1</td>

        <td>year1</td>
        <td>quantity1</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name1</td>

        <td>genre1</td>

        <td>year1</td>
        <td>quantity1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aname1</td>

        <td>genre1</td>

        <td>year1</td>
        <td>quantity1</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>aname1</td>

        <td>genre1</td>

        <td>year1</td>
        <td>quantity1</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

I try to sort my table by two columns: Name, Available but it does not work.

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const table = document.querySelector('.table_sort');
const indexToSorting = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].findIndex(cell => cell.classList.contains('sorted-asc'));
const availableIndexes = [...table.tHead.rows[0].cells].findIndex(cell => cell.classList.contains('available'));
const sortedRows = [...table.tBodies[0].rows].sort((rowA, rowB) => {
    let cellC;
    let cellD;
    const sortedRowsByAvailable = [...table.tBodies[0].rows].sort((rowC, rowD) => {
        cellC = rowC.cells[availableIndexes].innerText;
        cellD = rowD.cells[availableIndexes].innerText;
        const availableComparison = cellC.localeCompare(cellD);
        return availableComparison;

    });
    const cellA = rowA.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
    const cellB = rowB.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
    const nameComparison = cellA.localeCompare(cellB);
    return nameComparison !== 0 ? nameComparison : sortedRowsByAvailable
});

table.tBodies[0].append(...sortedRows);
```

});

My table is sorted by name, but i need to sort it by columns: name, available. Where is my mistake? I don't understand, please, help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an Array of Objects by two Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153846/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-two-properties)

Answer (score 0):

TBH, I didn't understand why you did `cellA - cellB`, but you need to add a comparison for `Available` cells in case `cellA` and `cellB` are equal.

```
const rowAAvailable = rowA.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
const rowBAbailable = rowB.cells[indexToSorting].innerText;
const nameComparison = cellA.localeCompare(cellB);
const availableComparison = rowAAvailable.localeCompare(rowBAbailable); // sorry for terrible naming, but you get the idea
return nameComparison !== 0 ? nameComparison : availableComparison
```

This will sort your table by name as the first priority and available the second one.

Comment: I edited question. Can you please check if this is correct

Comment: i have error: "condition is always true since type this and number have no overlap"

 const sortedRows=sortedRowsByName !== 0 ? sortedRowsByName : sortedRowsByAvailable

Comment: @kmj you have to use the comparison I wrote in the same sort, not in a separate one.

Comment: i edited question, but it does not work

Comment: it sorts by name

Comment: you don't need another sort. just change the return in your sort to the one I wrote

Comment: but how can i get cellC and cellD?

Comment: edited the answer. Pls look to the code part.