# jQuery: Using string passed by $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>Test</div>
</div>
```

and

```
$(['.b']).each(function () {
  console.log($('.a').find(this).text()); // Expecting to print "Test"
});
```

I expect the `console.log` to print `Test`, but it doesn't! Is this a jQuery bug?

Comment: What does square bracket in `['.b']` means?

Comment: @JustinJohn it is n array with one element. `$.each` can be used to loop over arrays or objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few problems here.

1. When you call jQuery with an array (like you're doing), jQuery expects it to be an array of DOM elements.
2. If you want to use `$.each`, use the [static version](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) that iterates over generic objects or arrays.

With both of those things said, there's *stil* an issue with using `$.each` with an array containing primitive values. The following code exhibits the same problem you were seeing:

```
$.each([".b"], function () {
    console.log($('.a').find(this).text()); // Expecting to print "Test"
});
```

Inside the callback function for `.each`, `this` is a `String` *object* and not a string *primitive*. To understand this, we need to look at what `.each` is doing under the hood:

```
for (; i < length;) {
    if (callback.apply(object[i++], args) === false) { // <----
        break;
    }
}
```

The important bit is the call to `apply`. According to the ECMAScript specification, when a primitive value is passed to `apply`, the value's `toObject` method is called:

> If thisArg is null or undefined, the called function is passed the global object as the this value. **Otherwise, the called function is passed ToObject(thisArg)** as the this value.

This explains why your code was not working-- `.find` expects a string primitive and not a String object.

This is why [the documentation for `$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) actually mentions using `this` with primitive values:

> (The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, **but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value.**).

Therefore the way to fix the problem with your code is to leverage the `element` argument that's passed to the callback function:

```
$.each([".b"], function (_, item) {
    console.log($('.a').find(item).text()); // Expecting to print "Test"
});
```

Comment: +1 - Although the (currently accepted) answer by @charlietftl basically says the same thing, this answer has a great explanation of why the `this` inside array based eaches is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `this` inside each when looping over an array. It works fine on objects or collection of elemnts but fails with arrays.

Use second argument of `each` to access array element

```
$(['.b']).each(function (index, item) {
  console.log($('.a').find(item).text()); // Expecting to print "Test"
});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/KbuZK/

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're on the dark side of JavaScript.

In JavaScript, `this` is always made into an `Object` so that `typeof this === "object"`, no matter what `this` was actually bound to. Even when a primitive string is bound to the `this` context (which you'd expect to give `typeof this === "string"`), `this` is actually a `String` object and `typeof this === "object"`. Here's a more [thorough explanation of this behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4390690/1321716).

When iterating over arrays of non-objects, you should use the second argument of your callback function as value.

```
$(['.b']).each(function (index, value) {
  console.log($('.a').find(value).text()); // Expecting to print "Test"
});
```