# Is `typeof foo === 'function'` the only way (other than attempting to call the object) to determine whether an object is callable?

Tags: javascript

Is `typeof foo === 'function'` the only way (other than attempting to call the object) to determine whether an object is callable?

If so, is this because it is otherwise impossible to distinguish between a callable object and an object that merely inherits from `Function.prototype`?

I note that until ES2015, the only way (other than supplying a string to `Function`, and possibly `eval`) to create a callable object, was to use the `function () {}` syntax, to create a function-object directly; and that ES2015 introduced a way of extending exotic objects like `Function`, enabling callable objects to be configured using the `class CallableClass extends Function` syntax, and instantiated using the `new CallableClass` syntax.

**To restate:** For all objects, `typeof` returns `'object'` **EXCEPT** for callable function-objects, for which it returns `'function'`. Is this the singular language feature, deliberately included, to enable userland identification of callable objects (because there was no other way)?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm seeing the reason behind the question. Does `typeof` not work in some cases? Is there a reason you'd need *another* way?

Comment: Prior to 2015 there was also the `Function` constructor (not that it was a great idea to use it).

Comment: `typeof new CallableClass` will still be `function` . You could look at how other's have addressed it ie. the [is-callable](https://github.com/inspect-js/is-callable/blob/main/index.js) package.

Comment: "`typeof new CallableClass` will still be `function`." I never said otherwise: in fact suggested that it would be.

Comment: Bringing us back to @deceze comment...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a variable is of function type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999998/check-if-a-variable-is-of-function-type)

Comment: @H.Almidan That is a different question.

Comment: You could check if the object has the `apply` or `call` method without having to invoke the function. This is a less canonical approach to `typeof fn === 'function'` but would work...in most cases .

Comment: @Nickofthyme That merely tests for the presence of that function on a property on an object on the prototype chain of the object under test. It doesn't test whether the object is callable. I can put `Function.prototype.call` on the prototype chain of any object I like.

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/1527678591063863296?s=20&t=LX30JXDYcbPMGUn4-Qv2Ow).

`typeof` was added to the language in JavaScript 1.1 (codified June, 1997).

A predicate to determine callability was rejected in favour of a tweaked `typeof` (to return `'function'` for callable objects) on the basis of parsimony. A callable object was defined as being "native" (presumably not "host" (eg browser) or "foreign" (eg. Java interop.)?), and implementing the internal [`[[Call]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-additional-essential-internal-methods-of-function-objects) method.

Thus: `typeof` returns `'object'` for every native object in JavaScript, except callable native objects, for which it returns `'function'`.

Note that:

- Exotic non-standard objects are permitted to return other values, but the value returned [must not match any of the values used in the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) (`'undefined'`, `'object'`, `'function'`, etc.).
- There is also the [`document.all` anomaly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#exceptions), but, of course, `document.all` is part of the Web platform and not JavaScript .

From [the JavaScript 1.1 specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-262_1st_edition_june_1997.pdf):

[image: typeof entry in JavaScript 1.1 specification]

Since the internal [`[[Call]]`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-additional-essential-internal-methods-of-function-objects) method is not directly visible to userland code; and since `[[Call]]` cannot be configured on an existing object by simply running the `Function` constructor against an existing object; and since adding `Function.prototype` to the prototype chain of an existing object is insufficient, there are only two ways of determining callability:

1. Attempt to run the object as a function
2. Use `typeof === 'function'`

**[Reference](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/1527678591063863296?s=20&t=LX30JXDYcbPMGUn4-Qv2Ow):**

Me:

> Was this because there was no other userland way to distinguish
> between a callable object created using `function foo(){}` and a
> non-callable object that merely inherited from `Function.prototype`?
> Or that perhaps there was a way, but that it was inconvenient?

Brendan Eich:

> Yes, and we anticipated foreign (Java, lol) objects and "host objects"
> that had callable objects which weren't native JS functions. I was
> adding typeof in Netscape 3 (JS1.1) so rather than a callable
> predicate, parsimonious to extend typeof slightly.