# JavaScript NULL Values

Tags: javascript

I am getting the following JavaScript error:

```
'value' is null or not an object
```

Can someone please let me know what is the best way to check whether an object's value is NULL in JavaScript as I have been using:

```
if ((pNonUserID !== "") || (pExtUserID !== "")){
```

Is this correct or is there a better way?

Comment: Your code is testing against an empty string, not `null`. If `pNonUserID = null;` then the expression will evaluate to `true`. But I think the error message is not related to the code you posted. The error is somewhere else.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript for more info

Comment: Felix is right. Worse yet, you are using the identical operator, which checks both value and type. If you used `!=` it would have worked (since it checks the value, and `null==""`). See my answer for more info.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't have to do that:

```
var n=null;

if(n)alert('Not null.'); // not shown
if(!n)alert('Is null.'); // popup is shown
```

Your error implies otherwise:

```
var n=null;

alert(n.something); // Error: n is null or not an object.
```

In the case above, something like this should be used:

```
if(n)alert(n.something);
```

Comment: The implication of your first code example is not correct. `if(!n)alert('Is null.');` will also alert `Is null` if `n == ''` or `n == 0`, and other cases.

Answer (score 3):

The !== operator returns true when two variables are not the same object. It doesn't look at the values of the objects at all

To test if something is null:

```
myVar == null
```

Your code was testing to see if the variable 'pNonUserId' referred to the same object as "", which can never be true as "" will always be a new instance of the empty string.

As an aside, a test such as:

```
var n = something();
// do stuff
if (n)
  doSomethingElse();
```

Is a bad idea. If n was a boolean and false, but you were expecting the if block to test nullify you'll be in for a shock.

Comment: I'm going to chime in here with a gripe about testing for null. It should be conceivable (and proper usage) to test for `var n = null; if (n !== null) { doSomething(n); }` but alas, a null Object will hapily evaluate to false above. If it was decided to make null an object, and it was decided that "===" should test for type as well as value, then the above should be valid code. Drives me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pNonUserID && pExtUserID)
{
   // neither pNonUserId nor pExtUserID are null here
}
```

Any Javascript variable automatically evaluates to true when it references an object.

What you were doing are comparisons to empty strings, which are not the same as null.

Answer (score 0):

null, undefined and empty string is consider as false in conditional statement.

so

```
if(!n) alert("n is null or undefined or empty string"); 
if(n) alert("n has some value");
```

therefor, inflagranti suggested condition will work perfectly for you

```
if(pNonUserID && pExtUserID) { 

}
```