# expressJS + MongoDB - login/register method

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I want to have login/register function in my expressJS API.
So now im just inserting password and email into my database, i want this function to first check if user with this email is already in database - if yes, send response that user is logged.
If not, just insert him to database.
Is it possible to handle some errors in here?

I already have it:

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
var email = req.body.email;
var pwd = req.body.pass;

db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
    collection.insert({login:email, password: pwd}, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
      res.send("OK");
        });
    });
};\
```

and dont know what's next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first try to find the user in your database. Assuming *email* is unique;

```
exports.login = function(req, res){
  var email = req.body.email;
  var pwd = req.body.pass;

  db.collection('users', function(err, collection) {
    if (err) return res.send(500, err);

    collection.findOne({login:email}, function(err, user) {
        // we found a user so respond back accordingly
        if (user) return res.send('user logged in');

        collection.insert({login:email, password: pwd}, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
          if (err) return res.send(500, err);
          res.send("OK");
        });
    });
  });
};
```

notice the `return`'s before the `res.send` calls when handling errors.

Comment: even if im typing the same email, it still inserts new document - are u sure that these conditions are good? I mean `if(user)` works in javascript? :)

Comment: should've added @Bulkan i think :)

Comment: @pawel using [mongoskin](https://github.com/kissjs/node-mongoskin) the callback passed to `findOne` is called with two arguments `err` and the `value` from the DB. If the query doesn't match anything then the `value` is set to _null_. 

In JavaScript [null](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5486264/1048697) is a _falsy_ value.