# JS error in IE7 / IE8 : 'var' has value Null or is not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

This snippet just makes IE7/IE8 crashes the page throwing error. I don't know why cause on chrome / FF, everything is fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/15/

The problem seems to be here :

```
            return event.Date.valueOf() === date.valueOf();
```

The error is :

Message:  **'Date' has value Null or is not an object**

What's causing this ? Thanks

**EDIT** I updated my code here http://jsfiddle.net/Zrz9t/15/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript

Comment: Updating to jQuery 1.5.2 should resolve your issue. I tried with 1.5.1 in jsFiddle and had no errors in IE9/IE8.

Comment: I got completely different error messages. jQuery 1.5 has some bugs that occur in IE9. Change to jQuery 1.5.1.

Comment: I was on jquery 1.5.1 -> updated to 1.5.2 and it didn't fixed the error

Comment: I've updated my code, you still don't see the error in IE7/8 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the following :

```
    var events =[
{ Url : "azerty", StartDate : new Date("04/17/2011") } ,
{ Url : "azerty2", StartDate : new Date("04/17/2011") } ,
];
```

Notice the last comma on the last line (which wasn't present on JsFiddle).

IE was the only one to yell at me for that extra comma.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

That script works fine in FF4 and IE8.

However, IE is picky about reserved words. Try renaming "Date" to something else.

Comment: I changed the name of the var (to StartDate) without no result. Will try updating jQuery

Comment: After adding `id="div"` to the HTML code I can click to a yellow cell and (ie. April 13th) and get a 404 error because it tries to load "http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/Five%20K%20for%20charity".

Comment: Sory, wrong code update, i've put back the alert(event.Title)

Comment: Works fine for me with IE 8.0.7601.17514 64-bit edition after fixing your `<div></div>` code to `<div id="div"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the Date is null.when you are trying to get the valueOf a null object it is throwing the error.

Comment: could you please give an example ?

Answer (score -1):

`event` is probably a reserved keyword in IE, try changing it to something else.