# JavaScript: What is the difference between `if (!x)` and `if (x == null)`?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between `if (!x)` and `if (x == null)`; that is, when can their results be different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript

Comment: I love [this article](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/). Did you know that both `'a' == false` and `'a' == true` are `false` =) Yeah. Go figure.

Comment: @Rudie: An apple is not an orange and an apple is not a banana. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Bergi Nothing. But did you know that both `'a' == false` and `'a' == true` are `false`. Or do you want to talk about fruit some more?

Comment: @Rudie: Yes, I knew and it makes only sense?

Comment: An apple is not an orange, and an apple is not **not** an orange.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`!x` will return `true` for every "falsy" value (empty string, `0`, `null`, `false`, `undefined`, `NaN`) whereas `x == null` will only return `true` if `x` **is** `null` (*edit:* or apparently `undefined` (see below)).

Try with `x = 0`, there is a difference.

You can say that the NOT operator `!` *converts* a value into its opposite boolean equivalent. This is different than actually *comparing* two values.

In addition, if you compare values with `==`, JavaScript does [*type conversion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) which can lead to unexpected behavior (like `undefined == null`). It is better to always use strict comparison `===` (value and type must be the same) and make use of type conversion only if you really know what you are doing.

Something to read:

- [Data Type Conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_Variables,_and_Literals#Data_Type_Conversion)
- [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)
- [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

---

**Update:**

For more information about the non-strict comparison of `null` and `undefined` (or the comparison in general), it is worth having a look at the [*specification*](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.9.3). The comparison algorithm is defined there (the comparison is `x == y`):

> 1. If Type(*x*) is the same as Type(*y*), then
>      (...)
> 2. If *x* is **null** and *y* is **undefined**, return **true**.
> 3. If *x* is **undefined** and *y* is **null**, return **true**.
> 4. (...)
>
> (...)

Comment: "undefined == null" returns true, too. which is why you better use "x === null".

Answer (score 4):

The results can be different if x is false, NaN, '' (empty string), undefined (using the strict comparison operator ===), or 0 (zero).

See [Felix Kling's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791158/javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-if-x-and-if-x-null/5791194#5791194) for an excellent summary of type comparison.

Comment: undefined type coerces to null, so (x == null) is true for undefined, though (x === null) is not.

Comment: Yes good catch @justkt, I shall update answer for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!x)
```

coerces x uses the internal ToBoolean function

```
if (x==null)
```

coerces both operands using the internal ToPrimitive function (which generally resolves each side to a number, occasionally a string, depending on the operands)

For full explanantion of ToBoolean vs ToPrimitive see http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Say x is a string.

```
x = undefined;
if(!x) {
   alert("X is not a truthy value");
}
if(x == null) {
   alert("X is null");
}

x = "";
if(!x) {
   alert("X is not a truthy value");
}
if(x == null) {
   alert("X is null");
}

x = null;
if(!x) {
   alert("X is not a truthy value");
}
if(x == null) {
   alert("X is null");
}
```

You'll notice that "X is not a truthy value" is shown in all three cases, but only in the case of X being undefined or null is "X is null" shown.

When X is a boolean value, then `(!x)` will be true when X is false but `(x == null)` will not be.  For numbers 0 and NaN are considered false values, so not X is truthy.

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/GNuHF/2), including the difference between `==` (equality using type conversion) and `===` (strict equality)

Answer (score 1):

`!x` tests for a false value. This will be true for any value that can propagate to false for whatever reason. This will be true for permutations of `false`, `0`, etc etc.

`x == null` is different because `var x = 0` will NOT be null... but WILL be false.