# JavaScript If/Else Conditions & Comparisons - Differences

Tags: javascript, casting, comparison, boolean, conditional-statements

Okay, here's my short question:

I know that `===` and `!==` operators will compare the types and then the values, and that `==` and `!=` will cast the types and then just compare the values.

What about `if(myVar)` and `if(!myVar)`?

Is there any difference in the behavior from `if(myVar == true)` and `if(myVar == false)`?

Comment: Yes, they're different. It's been discussed several times on SO.

Comment: Yes. See these two related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496727/why-does-0-a-b-behave-different-than-0-true-a-b and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791158/javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-if-x-and-if-x-null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. As you already mentioned, if you compare a value with `==`, *type conversion* takes places.

If the values are *not* of the same type, they will both be converted to either *strings* or *numbers*.  If one of the values is a *boolean* and the other is not, both values will be converted to *numbers*.

The comparison algorithm is defined in [section 11.9.3 of the specification](http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3). The important step is here:

> 7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison `x == ToNumber(y)`.

So `true` is converted to a number first and later `myVar` will be converted to a number as well.

---

If you only have `if(myVar)` though, then [the value is converted to a boolean](http://es5.github.com/#x12.5):

> 2. If `ToBoolean(GetValue(exprRef))` is true, then

---

[`ToNumber` *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3) and [`ToBoolean` *<sup>[spec]</sup>*](http://es5.github.com/#x9.2) can return very different results.

---

**Note**: If `myVar` is actually a boolean, then there is no difference between `if(myVar == true)` and `if(myVar)`.

Comment: Thanks, that's the best explanation to me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a difference. For example:

```
if('true' == true) {
    alert("This doesn't happen");
}

if('true') {
    alert("But this does happen.");
}
```

The reason? They're both converted to `number`s for comparison. `'true'` is converted to `NaN` and `true` is converted to `1`.

Avoid this silliness and never write `== true` or `== false`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there is a huge difference in both  `if(myVar) and if(!myVar)` and `if(myVar == true) and if(myVar == false)`

In `if(myVar) and if(!myVar)` , !myVar will return true for every "false" value (empty string, 0, null, false, undefined, NaN)

while `if(myVar == true)` and `if(myVar == false)` check whether myVar value is true or false. Even if myVar value is NULL, NaN or undefined 0, it'll compare like

`if(NULL == true)`

Summing up :

```
NOT operator'!' converts a value into its opposite boolean equivalent. This is different than actually comparing two values.
And if you compare values with '==', JavaScript does type conversion which can lead to unexpected behavior (like undefined == null).
```

Comment: What does *whether it contains anything or not* mean exactly?

Comment: @FelixKling It obviously means if it is `null, false, NaN, undefined, "", +0, or -0` :P

Comment: @FelixKling :  "false" values i.e. empty string, 0, null, false, undefined, NaN

Comment: Yeah, I guessed so ;) But the choice of words was not very precise. Sorry for nitpicking.