# Checking if multiple variables is not null, undefined or empty in an efficient way

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment I have an if condition like this:

```
if(
  (variable != null && variable != '' && !variable) &&
  (variable2 != null && variable2 != '' && !variable2) &&
  (variable3 != null && variable3 != '' && !variable3)
  //etc..
)
```

I need to use it to check if multiple variables have value (were not left out), but I feel like this is a messy solution and wanted to ask if there is a more efficient way? Maybe additional checks as well?

Comment: I think `if(var)` will do the job. (This will test if the variable contains something)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you check for an empty string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154059/how-do-you-check-for-an-empty-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Because `if(variable)` ignores any `falsy` value, this will work for you

```
if(variable && variable2 && variable3)
```

The following values are always falsy in JS:

```
false.
0 (zero)
"" (empty string)
null.
undefined.
NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)
```

### Update:-

If there is a case when you want to execute if block even if the value is 0, you have to add an extra check saying either 0 or some other value.

```
if((variable || variable === 0) && (variable2 || variable2 === 0) && (variable3 || variable3 === 0))
```

Comment: But if var  = 0 it will considered false too

Comment: Seems to work for testing false too?  (this might save someone 2 minutes):  `var variable = ""; var variable2 = ""; var variable3 = ""; if (!variable && !variable2 && !variable3) { console.log("hi") }`

Answer (score 18):

If IE support matter to you (IE9+), you could use the following solution.

You could use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). In a nutshell this array method will return true if any of the elements in the array meet a certain condition. This condition will be `el == null` this will work because `undefined == null` and `null == null` both resolve in `true`

See this stackoverflow post for more information

[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

`Array.prototype.some()` browser support (93% time of writing) [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=some)

```js
var a = 5;
var b = null;
var c = undefined;

if ( [a,b,c].some(el => el == null) ) {          
  console.log("You f*d up")
}
```

Or you could use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes?v=control)

See support (93% time of writing) here [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=includes)

```js
var a = 5;
var b = null;
var c = undefined;
   
 if ( [a,b,c].includes(undefined) || [a,b,c].includes(null) ) {          
   console.log("You f*d up")
 }
```

If you want good browser support and you don't mind an external library, use [lodash](https://lodash.com).

```js
var a = 5;
var b = null;
var c = undefined;

if ( _.some([a,b,c], el => _.isNil(el)) ) {
  console.log("You f*d up")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 9):

If your variables are containing some values that are *truthy*, like a string, and that is considered positive in your condition, then you could simply check using `Array.prototype.every()`...

```
if (![var1, var2, var3].every(Boolean)) {
     throw new exc;
}
```

Which will check to ensure every variable has a truthy value.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are checking for truthy values? If so, you can just do:

`variable && variable2 && variable3`

Comment: it does not return true but the last variable value if all are valid valeus.. anything to get true?

Comment: Cast the expression to a boolean `Boolean(variable && variable2)` or `!!(variable && variable2)`

Answer (score 0):

See [JavaScript: What is the difference between `if (!x)` and `if (x == null)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791158/javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-if-x-and-if-x-null)

!variable will be true for all falsy values so you only have to

```
if(variable1 && variable2 && variable3 && ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Long hand -

```
 if (var1 !== null || var1 !== undefined || var1 !== '') {
   let var2 = var1;
 }
```

Short hand -

```
 const var2 = var1  || '';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let variable null;
let variable2 undefined;
let variable3 'string';
let variable4 '';
let variable5 true;
let variable6 false;
let variable7 0;
let variable8 1;
```

Validating multiple values using the filter function.  One could expect this example to return true as the count would be 5 for (variable, variable2, variable4, variable6, variable7)

```
if([variable, variable2, variable3, variable4, variable5, variable6, variable7, variable8]
  .filter(q=>!q).length > 0) {
   //take action
}
```