# Difference between if(!x) and if(x==null)

Tags: c++, if-statement

if we are writing a code in C++ or any other language and we use `if else` statement there then what is the difference in `if(!x)` and `if(x==null)`.
I was working on a code and I came through these two statements in a single code so I was pretty curious to know the difference between the above mentioned two.

Comment: `if (x == null)` is not C++ (unless you previously defined a variable `null`). Did you mean `if (x == nullptr)` ?

Comment: There is no difference in terms of functionality. However the `if (!x)` is less readable, with `if (x==nullptr)` I already know that `x` is a pointer. Implicit conversions is a pain.

Comment: The *"or any other language"* part makes this question too broad, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791158/javascript-what-is-the-difference-between-if-x-and-if-x-null which has a different answer from the C++ ones.

Comment: In C++, it depends on what `x` and `null` are as neither has a standard meaning (`NULL` is something distinct from `null`). If `x` is a numeric or pointer type (e.g. `int`,  `aStruct *`) and `null` is a variable or constant with value zero (and of a type that can be compared with `x`) then `!x` and `x == null` are (typically) equivalent. If `x` is an instance of a `class` type then meanings of `!x` and `x == null` depend on what `operator` functions are defined for that type (and those functions, in combination, may or may not be defined in a way that makes `!x` and `x == null` equivalent).

Comment: If we're talking **C++**, and assuming `x` is a pointer, then `if (!x)` is commonly used idiomatic shorthand for `if (x == nullptr)`. Whereas, assuming `null` is undefined, `if (x==null)` won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

`!x` will return `true` for every falsy value (`null`, `false`). Where as `x == null` , will only return `true`, if `x` is `null`.

Comment: Also note that null has to be defined somewhere or this won't work.

Comment: `x == nullptr` also requires `x` to be a pointer. It won't work if it's a boolean.

Comment: If you are "quoting" this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5791194/4944425), please note that it's about a different language (JavaScript).