# How to check DOM element is present or not in plain Javascript

Tags: javascript

Any idea how to check Dom elements is present or not in plain javascript using id

I was searching for stack overflow and some discussions but every answer is pointing towards **jquery** `if($('#frameBox').length == 0) { .... }`

I have tried something like `if(document.getElementById('frameBox').length == 0)` but it is not working

Comment: `getElementById('frameBox')`. The `#` is jQuery's way of identifying an ID

Comment: What do you want? A count of all elements?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a div exists with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899175/check-if-a-div-exists-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if element exists in the visible DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5629684/how-to-check-if-element-exists-in-the-visible-dom)

Comment: Check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940533/how-to-check-dom-element-is-present-or-not-in-plain-javascript/48940566#48940566) @ojusKulkarni for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work, because [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) returns a single HTML element, not an array-like collection of elements that has a `length` property, which you can get.

Also, note that, since you're trying to get an element by its id, you'll end up having one element returned at all times anyway, or `null`, if there's no element matching the given id.

For multiple grouped elements, try using classes and [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Then, you can use `length` on that.

**Example Code:**

```
// Check if an element with id 'frameBox' exists.
if (document.getElementById("frameBox")) {
  //...
}

// Check if there are any elements with class 'frameBox'.
if (document.getElementsByClassName("frameBox").length) {
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll`: eg:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#frameBox");
console.log(elements.length);
```

Although, you should not use the same id on multiple elements, that's what classes are for.

Answer (score 0):

**id** of an element is supposed to be unique. So **document.getElementById** would return only one element.

You can use a **class** instead of **id**. document.getElementsByClassName return all the elements which matches with the class.