# How do I hide a div based on whether another div is present on a page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to hide a div based on the presence of another div on the page.

Heres my HTML & JavaScript:

```js
// IIFE to enable `$` as jQuery
;
(function($) {
  // document ready
  $(function() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $description = document.querySelector("#coach2.et_pb_blurb_description");
      if ($description.length) {
        $('#coachtwocol').hide();
      }
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

```html
<div id="coachtwocol">
  <div id="coach2">
    <div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
      <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
        <h4><span>Coach:</span></h4>
        <div class="et_pb_blurb_description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to hide #coachtwocol if .et_pb_blurb_description is not present under #coach2 (the div .et_pb_blurb_description is not loaded on to the page if it is not filled in on the back end)

I believe the issue lies in my query selector but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with it or how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: is this line copy and paste error?  `$(document).ready(function() {`

Comment: Your logic has two document readies in it.  You only need one, and you can use `jQuery(function($){})` to avoid the outer IIFE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a div exists with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6899175/check-if-a-div-exists-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

`#coach2.et_pb_blurb_description` looks for a SINGLE element that both has the ID "coach2" AND the class "et_pb_blurb_description".

That is not the case. You're dealing with two elements, one the child of the other, so you need a space in your selector.

```
document.querySelector('#coach2 .et_pb_blurb_description')...
```

[EDIT]

OK, if it's still not working then it's time for some debugging. With selectors, never assume they're matching what you think they do/should. So let's test them. I'll also harmonise them both to use jQuery, since you appear to use it for one and not the other.

```
  let $description = $("#coach2.et_pb_blurb_description"),
      toHide = $('#coachtwocol');
  if ($description.length) {
      console.log('Found selector 1');
      if (toHide.length) {
          console.log('Found selector 2');
          toHide.hide();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Err, so you kinda left out that they were not using jQuery to do the lookup...

Comment: You need the class selector on `et_pb_blur_description`

Comment: Hi Utkanos,

I have tried this code before (using a space between the id and the class) with no luck, I assume this is meant to be "$('#coach2 .et_pb_blurb_description')"

Comment: Yeap, shoddy on my part, I rushed it. Now corrected. Yes, Josh, you assume correct.

Comment: @Utkanos thanks for confirming but this code still doesn't seem to be working for me? any other ideas what could be going wrong? 

Thanks for the response btw :)

Comment: @Utkanos thanks for the response again, this still doesn't seem to be working, I tried:

```<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let $description = $("#coach2 .et_pb_blurb_description");
      let $toHide = $('#coachtwocol');
  
  if ($description.length) {
      console.log('Found selector 1');
      if (toHide.length) {
          console.log('Found selector 2');
          toHide.hide();
      }
  }
    });
  })(jQuery);
</script>```

and can't see anything in the console. (sorry, I don't know how to paste that code to look better)

Comment: OK so if you don't see anything in the console then there's wider issues. Your script is possibly running before the DOM has loaded, so try encapsulating it in a DOM-ready event callback. If that fails, try to recreate the problem in a JS Fiddle or similar.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple typos in your code that are leading to odd behavior. First, like @Utkanos mentioned `#coach2.et_pb_blurb_description` is looking for an element like `<div id="coach2" class="et_pb_blurb_description">` which doesn't exist. You likely want to use the selector with a space like `#coach2 .et_pb_blurb_description` to select any elements with a class of `eb_pb_blurb_description` which are children of an element with an ID of `coach2`.

If you currently run your script, you get the error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` because you're missing a set of closing `)}`. Additionally, you have multiple `onready` functions with slightly different syntax that can be cleaned up.

Removing duplicate `onready` functions and fixing your selector:

```js
// IIFE to enable `$` as jQuery
(function($) {
  var $description = $("#coach2 .et_pb_blurb_description");
  if ($description.length) {
    console.log('description exists');
    $('#coachtwocol').hide();
  } else {
    console.log('description does not exist');
  }
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="coachtwocol">
  <div id="coach2">
    <div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
      <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
        <h4><span>Coach:</span></h4>
        <div class="et_pb_blurb_description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @WOUNDEDStevenJones 

I've tried this code in JSFiddle and it works fine but for some reason, there is an issue when trying to implement it on the website.

I'm getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined" in the console.

Comment: Nothing with this script includes concatenation (or a property named `concat`), so that sounds like it's a different line of code that's giving you a problem. Can you look in your code for `concat` or `.concat`? The error message should also include a line number that will point you to where it's failing. Likely you have something like `test.concat` but `test` is undefined, so it's throwing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code  works for you

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        var $description = document.querySelectorAll("#coach2");
        if ( $description.length>=0){
            $('#coachtwocol').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
<body>
    <div id="coachtwocol">
        <div id="coach2">
          <div class="et_pb_blurb_content">
                <div class="et_pb_blurb_container">
                      <h4><span>Coach:</span></h4>
              <div class="et_pb_blurb_description"></div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
</html>
```