# is javascript null separate type of object's value?

Tags: javascript

According to "8.2 The Null Type" chapter of Ecma-262 "null" is type.

But typeof(null) is object, so null is just a value of type object.

How could it be?

Comment: This might shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug. This will be fixed in ES6.

In ES6

`typeof null === "null";`