# Why does (true > null) always return true in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Can some tell me why the following code returns true in JavaScript?

```
console.log(true > null); //returns true
```

Comment: Yes because null is a falsy expression (then *false*) and comparison operator will convert it to a _number_ (then true = 1 and false = 0).

Comment: **@Adriano** post it as answer is just that!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/null-object-in-javascript

Comment: @elclanrs I'm lazy to write a complete answer with references to JavaScript standard (for who is interested just start from section 11.8.2).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`null` is like `false` in this case, wich is `0` as a number. `true` is `1` as a number.

`1` is bigger (`>`) than `0`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was wondering why is null === 0 false? Then I realised it needs to be coerced. So for those who need absolute proof, try + null === 0 which evaluates to true proving that indeed null is coerced to 0. Just thought this might help others.

Answer (score 7):

They are converted to numbers, `null` gives `0` and `true` gives `1`

http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5

> If it is not the case that both Type(*px*) is String and
>   Type(*py*) is String, then
>
> 1. Let *nx* be the result of calling ToNumber(*px*). Because *px* and *py*
>                  are primitive values evaluation order is not important.
> 2. Let *ny* be the result of calling ToNumber(*py*).

```
Number(null) //0
Number(true) //1
```

Answer (score 2):

May be because `true = 1` where `null = 0`

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript does a lot of type coercion in the background and a lot of the results you'll find aren't useful (see http://wtfjs.com/).

In this case, true which is coerced as 1 is greater than null which is coerced to 0.  Since 1 is greater than 0 the result is true.

> If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted to
>   1 if it is true and +0 if it is false.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score 1):

What's happening behind is that the relational operators ( `>` in this case) perform type coercion before doing the comparison. When doing the `ToPrimitive`, true gets coerced to a 1, and null to a 0.
You can check details here of how the operators actually work [here](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.8.2)

Answer (score 0):

The code is incorrect, you need to do:

```
console.log(true > typeof null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The compare operator ">" forces both it's left and right side to be converted to numbers.
Number(true) is 1, Number(null) is 0, so what is in the paranthesis is taken as "1>0", which is always true in result.