# why all falsy values in javascript aren't equal to false when tested for equality

Tags: javascript, boolean

I was checking the equality of all the falsey values from the list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19839952/465053):

Below code for three falsey values namely `null`, `undefined` and `NaN` doesn't print `hi`:

```
if(null == false) console.log('hi');
if(undefined == false) console.log('hi');
if(NaN == false) console.log('hi');
```

All other falsey values end up printing the text `hi` as shown below:

```
if('' == false) console.log('hi');
if(0x0 == false) console.log('hi');
if(false == false) console.log('hi');
if(0.0 == false) console.log('hi');
if(0 == false) console.log('hi');
```

Can anyone help me understand the reason behind this behavior?

**Update for future readers**:

Three interesting reads if you are trying to wrap your head around weirdness of falsy values and equality operators in JavaScript:

1. [why null==undefined is true in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16607761/465053)
2. [Why does (true > null) always return true in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11614746/465053)
3. [What exactly is Type Coercion in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19915688/465053)

Comment: The semantics of the `==` operator are not the same as the rules for evaluation of arbitrary values as boolean.

Comment: Read here about type coercion you will understand it bit better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19915688/what-exactly-is-type-coercion-in-javascript

Comment: Specifically, the `==` (or "loose equality") operator [compares two values for equality  _after_ converting both values to a common type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using)

Comment: Never use loose comparison to compare against a boolean. Try `if('0' == false) console.log('hi');`. Surprised? If you want to know what's happening exactly, [have a look at the spec](https://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison). That algorithm is easy to follow.

Comment: @FelixKling `'0'` is simply a non-empty string so it will pass the equality test with `false`. Any non-empty string is a truthy value.

Comment: Did you run the code?

Comment: Yes. It prints `hi`.

Comment: I just reread your comment. If non-empty strings are truthy, why should they be equal to `false`?  `'foo'` is also non-empty and *not* equal to `false`. Your question is about falsy values. Aren't you surprised that both `''` and `'0'` are equal to `false`?

Comment: The abstract equality operation in JavaScript is _heuristic_. Read section 7.1.12 (of ES6 standard) to see how it actually works. Beware that "Type( null)" is Null, not Object. The examples posted convert `false` to the number zero for comparison. None of  `null`, `undefined` or `NaN` is equal to numeric zero following steps in the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator has its own semantics. You're comparing behaviors that are not defined to be the same.

If you want to see how the normal "truthy/falsy" evaluation works, you should use `!value` or `!!value` instead of `value == false` or `value == true`:

```
if (!null) console.log("hi");
if (!NaN) console.log("hi");
```