# Comparing to null - !== vs != in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, compare

Ok, so I installed Linter on my Sublime editor while working on my node.js app. One of the things that it caught said that I should always use !== to compare an object to null (I usually use != ).

So I changed it...but then I noticed that the !== wasn't working.

---

**UPDATE**
Ok, so it may be a bit more complicated than I originally thought. In my real code I was using !== with the node.js GLOBAL object.

```
console.log('Global User: ' + GLOBAL.User);

if (GLOBAL.User != null)
{
    console.log('User is not null');
}
```

The console line prints even when GLOBAL.User is null...

Perhaps this object is special?

---

Ok, so after reading through the comments and looking at my code, I have learned that !== can have issues if the object is undefined rather than null (see this post: [Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-compared-to-undefined?lq=1)).

So in my case, my global variable could be, depending on when this method is called, undefined, null, or full of data. I am going to go back and update my code so that it is never undefined and then !== will work consistently.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://jsfiddle.net/zA4Du/)

Comment: Unable to repeat your experiment. My x === null when I do your code.

Note that null == undefined is true.
null === undefined is false.

JavaScript is fun!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-compared-to-undefined

Comment: It shouldn't print that line.

Comment: did you clear the console (console.clear())? Maybe you are seeing a log from before

Comment: Are you sure the value you are comparing to is `null` and not `undefined`?

Comment: Perhaps I am dumb, but I have always compared null and undefined equally...never had a problem

Comment: Well what is `Global.User` anyway?

Comment: Global or GLOBAL is how node.js designates a global variable. After looking at it, depending on where I am in my code it is either undefined, null, or loaded with data.

Comment: You can use `if (!someVariable)` to test if _someVariable_ is null, undefined, false, zero, an empty string, or any [falsey value](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Your `global.User` is `undefined`, not `null`. When using `==` they evaluate to equal, but with `===` the items you are comparing need to be the same type. `undefined` has the type `undefined` and `null` has the type `object`.

`undefined` and `null` are very similar, but they generally mean two very different things. Usually `undefined` is the result when something has had no value assigned to it, whereas `null` has a value, and the value is explicitly set to "nothing".

Comment: So...if an object could be either undefined or null depending on the situation it is safer to use == rather than ===?

Comment: @David Generally I'd avoid the ambiguity and make sure it is initialized to `null`. As with any situation, the few possible factors you need to take into account, the easier it will be to reason about an issue.

Answer (score 15):

The only value that doesn't equal itself in JavaScript is `NaN`. If `null === null` is `false`, then your JavaScript engine has serious problems ;)

To make sure your conditional statement is well written, always use the braces.

```
var x = null;
if (x !== null) {
    console.log('x is not equal to null');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It is even  more simple

```
var x = null;
    if (x) 6 
    if (!x) 7
```

the result is

```
undefined
7
```