# Can't print Javascript array completely

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to iterate through the array of numbers and print all its elements

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function q(arr) {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i]) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

q(arr);
```

The array contains 11 elements, but my code prints only 10 (except the 1'st element). But why? And how can i print my array completely?

Thank you

Comment: What's they point of `if(arr[i])`? Hint, hint

Comment: What is `if(arr[i])` supposed to do?

Comment: check, if `arr[i]` exists

Comment: @Ludmila http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961528/javascript-check-if-array-exist-if-not-create-it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first element of `arr` array (`0`) evaluates to `false` inside your `if` statement.

Here is the working snippet:

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function q(arr) {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] || arr[i] === 0) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

q(arr);
```

To get what you want, your `if` statement should look like this: `arr[i] || arr[i] === 0`. And i reccomend you to read about **coercion** to understand what's really is going on.

### And you don't really need `if` statement here

Answer (score 3):

In the array element [`0` is a falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) so it won't get printed since there is an `if` statement which checks the elements is `truthy`.

There is no reason to use an `if` condition if you just want to iterate so remove the if condition to get it print.

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function q(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}

q(arr);
```

---

**FYI :** In case you want to avoid null values then use condition as `arr[i] !== null` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your if statement. The arr[0] returns 0 which is a falsy value and thus the code inside the if statement will not be executed. Remove the if statement and it should work as i is always < than the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

Just remove if condition . when `if(arr[0])` it will not satisfied

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function q(arr) {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    
      console.log(arr[i]);
    
  }
}

q(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

just check if each element !== null

```js
var arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function q(arr) {
  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] != null) {
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
  }
}

q(arr);
```

Comment: Always compare to `null` using abstract (`!=`) instead of script (`!==`) equality. (See [16204840](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16204840/javascript-comparing-to-null-vs))

Comment: I thouht i could because null in an Object. But i'm far for being an expert, so I keep your advice.