# how to check document.getElementbyId contains null or undefined value in it?

Tags: javascript

```
if(typeof    (document.getElementById("courseId").value!=="undefined") || document.getElementById("courseId").value!==null)
    {
        Courseid = document.getElementById("courseId").value;
    }
```

Comment: What is `#courseId`? An `<input type="text" />`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-compared-to-undefined?rq=1

Comment: OP is clearly a new user of SO and perhaps was not used to finding duplicate questions. It looks like a very reasonable question to me. Were all those downvotes actually necessary?

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate since it's clearly asking about the type of a value in an input.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

rewrite it that way:

```
if(document.getElementById("courseId") && document.getElementById("courseId").value)
{
    CourseId = document.getElementById("courseId").value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you explicitly want to check for undefined and null you can do

```
if(document.getElementById('courseId') === null || 
   document.getElementById('courseId') === undefined) {
    //logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An input's value will never be `null` or undefined - it will be the empty string, `""`.

Comment: `document.getElementById("myInput").value.typeof` returns `undefined` for me. Even when I assign a value to it by typing in the input box like typing `20` it still returns `undefined`.