# javascript null value - is it an object

Tags: javascript, types

I'm analysing javascript datatypes and I found something extremely strange:

```
> typeof null
"object"
> null instanceof Object
false
```

Currently I've got no idea how could I explain that. I thought that everything that has `typeof === "object"` will have `Object.prototype` in its prototype chain. If `null` is not an `object`, then why does `typeof` return that?

PS somebody already wrote me *welcome to the wacky world of javascript* ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7968470/594589

Comment: On a slightly related note, look at `Object.create(null)`

Comment: @SLaks that is slightly different, though, because you're saying "the new Object's prototype shouldn't be anything" and `Object.create(null).__proto__` actually gets set to `null`.

Comment: @PaulS.: Yes; that's why I said "_slightly_ related".  In particular, not everything that has typeof === "object" will have Object.prototype in its prototype chain.

Comment: crazy as it seems, but thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has historical reasons:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null

> typeof null === 'object'; // This stands since the beginning of JavaScript
>   In the first implementation of JavaScript, JavaScript values were represented as a type tag and a value. The type tag for objects was 0. null was represented as the NULL pointer (0x00 is most platforms). Consequently, null had 0 as type tag, hence the bogus typeof return value. (reference needed)
>
> A fix was proposed for ECMAScript (via an opt-in), but was rejected. It would have resulted in typeof null === 'null'.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I've already accepted it, but... still I don't know the answer. Is `null` an object? As far as I understood, it's _not_, right?

Comment: Right, it's not an [object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6), it's a [primitive value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2) of the type [`Null`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.2), and in a perfect world `typeof null` would return `null`.