# When is a variable's data type in javascript `Null`?

Tags: javascript

Is it actually possible to get the `Null` data type as a return from the `typeof` function - if so what case yields that result, when is a variable actually of the  `Null` type?

```
    typeof myVAR; //gives me "undefined" before the variable declaration

    var myVAR;
    typeof myVAR; //also gives me "undefined"

    myVAR = null; //assigned the null object
    typeof myVAR; //gives me "Object" (which I guess makes sense because `null` is an object and that's what I assigned to the variable)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined)

Comment: @PSL not quite, that explains what the `null` value is - but my question is geared more towards `Null` (the data type)?

Comment: Ok. I shall retract my close vote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`typeof` never returns `"null"`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3), but there is an [internal null type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.2):

#### Typeof Results:

- **Undefined:** "undefined"
- **Null:** "object"
- **Boolean:** "boolean"
- **Number:** "number"
- **String:** "string"
- **Object (native and does not implement [[Call]]):** "object"
- **Object (native or host and does implement [[Call]]):** "function"
- **Object (host and does not implement [[Call]]):** Implementation-defined except may not be "undefined", "boolean", "number", or "string".

The only way to test for null would be a direct comparison with the `null` value, using the `===` operator.

Comment: hmm..thank you, that answers part of my question, but can a variable ever be of `Null` data type?

Comment: @SuviVignarajah: A variable can have the `null` value, which is the only value of the `Null` data type.

Comment: I understand now - I did some research, seems like the `Undefined` data types "special" value is also `undefined` (similar to `Null` and `null`). You can declare a variable `var myVAR = undefined`, and `typeof myVAR` will yield `undefined` still. Seems like the `typeof` in javascript just doesn't return `Null` or `null` as one of the types like you state in your answer.

Comment: @SuviVignarajah: typeof doesn't return the actual name of the internal type - that may be slightly confusing.

Comment: Slightly..on another note, this explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#null) gives me some closure though about why `typeof null` yields `"object"`.