# Why does typeof(null) return "object", but you can't assign properties to it?

Tags: javascript

Bear with me here, I'm going to try something stupid.

When I evaluate `typeof(null)` in the console, I get `"object"`, so logically, I should be able to assign properties to it, but  `null.foo = 42` gives `TypeError: Cannot set property 'foo' of null`.

Is Javascript just picky when it comes to which global objects are mutable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This page has a nice description of the history here surrounding why `typeof(null)` gives "object":
[JS Data Types - Null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Null)

Here is the relevant portion (although I would suggest you read the whole post):

> Why does `typeof null` return `"object"`?
> `// What's happening here?`
> `typeof null === "object"; // true`
>
> The answer might disappoint some, but the truth is simply because the table above says to do so.
>
> The reasoning behind this is that `null`, in contrast with `undefined`, was (and still is) often used where objects appear. In other words, `null` is often used to signify an empty reference to an object. When Brendan Eich created JavaScript, he followed the same paradigm, and it made sense (arguably) to return `"object"`. In fact, the ECMAScript specification defines `null` as *the primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value* (ECMA-262, 11.4.11).

To draw a parallel here, consider `typeof(NaN) === "number"`.  So why does JavaScript give "number" as the type of `NaN` (not a number)?  It is because `NaN` is used where numbers appear, it is a value that represents the intentional absence of a number value.  Similar reasoning applies to `null`, the only difference being that `null` is implemented as a primitive and `NaN` is actually implemented as a `Number` object (so `NaN.foo = 42` would actually work).

Comment: What I get out of this is, `null` is an empty reference, but it's still a reference. Is that a reasonable rationale to draw from the paradigm Eich followed? Similarly, I would say that `undefined` is simply a reference that does not exist. Am I on the right track here?

Comment: @DesertIvy You can think of `null` as an empty reference, but I would actually try to avoid the word "reference" because that means different things to different people depending on their favorite language, so it might cause confusion.  I like "`null` is a primitive value that represents the absence of an object" better.

Comment: That makes sense. Going back to the italicized text in the documentation cited in your answer, it seems that the word `intentional` is extremely relevant to this circumstance.

Answer (score 4):

The specification  determines that [`typeof`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3) should return `"object"` for the `null` value, and at the same time [defines `null` as a primitive](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2):

> A primitive value is a member of one of the following built-in types: Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, and String; an object is a member of the remaining built-in type Object; and a function is a callable object.

So, `null` is not an object. That's why you can't assign properties to it. The value returned by `typeof` is artificial.

Comment: +1 for the explicit statement *"null is not an object"*. From [4.3.11](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.11) *"primitive value that represents the intentional absence of any object value."*

Comment: Interesting answer. Is there any inherent advantage in `typeof` returning such a value? `typeof(undefined)` indeed returns `undefined`, so why wouldn't `typeof(null)` similarly return `null`?

Comment: @DesertIvy Caught your comment too late... F.J's answer has a good explanation of the rationale behind it, as you probably know by now.

Answer (score -1):

null is a primitive data type. it has one value: null. it does not have a constructor. it is an object that is build in to the language. you can't create an object of the type null, in other words.