# Is null considered zero and undefined not a number on arithmetic expressions?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined, nan, zero

Is `null` evaluated to `0` and `undefined` to `NaN` on arithmetic expressions?

According to some testing it seems so:

```
> null + null
0

> 4 + null
4

> undefined + undefined
NaN

> 4 + undefined
NaN
```

Is it safe or correct to assume this? (a quote from a documentation would be A+).

Comment: It depends on the other argument type too : `"A"+null`

Comment: [The spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)

Comment: @dystroy, yup but that would be a *string concatenation*, and not an *arithmetic expression*.

Comment: @Pointy, I can find the spec, no problem. What I would like is a quote from it ;)

Comment: It's safe like a juggler with 10 torches. If he knows exactly what he doing, then it's safe.

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined

Comment: @talles I find the difference of dubious use as the difference is resolved dynamically depending on the values.

Comment: @talles it's exactly the same operator - `+`

Comment: @talles that's a link straight to the description of the `+` operator

Comment: @Pointy, Just because it's the same character, doesn't mean it's the same operator. `string + <thing>` is string concatenation, while `int + <thing>` is integer addition.

Comment: @BrianS well yes obviously the *operations* are different; my point is that it's that process described in the spec that determines what an expression involving that operator *means*.  The Expression syntax doesn't distinguish between numeric addition and string concatenation, in other words.

Answer (score 16):

> Is null evaluated to 0 and undefined to NaN on arithmetic expressions? Is it safe or correct to assume this?

Yes, it is. An "arithmetic expression" would use the [`ToNumber` operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3):

```
 Argument Type | Result
 --------------+--------
 Undefined     | NaN
 Null          | +0
 …             |
```

It is used in the following "arithmetic" expressions:

- [prefix](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.4)/[postfix](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.3) increment and decrement
- the unary [`+`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) and [`-`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.7) operators
- the [`+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) if none of the two arguments is a string
- [subtraction](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2), [multiplication, division and modulo](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.5) operation
- [relational](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.8.5) operators if not both arguments are strings

It is not used by the [equality](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3) operators, so `null == 0` is false (and `null !== 0` anyway)!

Answer (score 5):

It seems safe to assume so since, in an arithmetic expression (*e.g.* [addition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1)), the method [ToNumber](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3) would be called on it, evaluating `NaN` and `+0` from `undefined` and `null` respectively:

```
                     To Number Conversions
╔═══════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Argument Type ║                   Result                   ║
╠═══════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Undefined     ║ NaN                                        ║
║               ║                                            ║
║ Null          ║ +0                                         ║
║               ║                                            ║
║ Boolean       ║ The result is 1 if the argument is true.   ║
║               ║ The result is +0 if the argument is false. ║
║               ║                                            ║
║ Number        ║ The result equals the input argument (no   ║
║               ║ conversion).                               ║
║               ║                                            ║
║ String        ║ See grammar and note below.                ║
║               ║                                            ║
║ Object        ║ Apply the following steps:                 ║
║               ║   1. Let primValue be ToPrimitive(input    ║
║               ║      argument, hint Number).               ║
║               ║   2. Return ToNumber(primValue).           ║
╚═══════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

[ECMAScript Language Specification - ECMA-262 Edition 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3)

Comment: However note that if the *other* operand to `+` is a string, then `ToString` is called and string concatenation is carried out. So `null + "hello"` is the string `"nullhello"`.

Answer (score 1):

Without being type bound,

```
null == false == 0

null !== false !== 0
```

http://www.mapbender.org/JavaScript_pitfalls:_null,_false,_undefined,_NaN#0_6

With that said, `null == 0`, `null + 4 = 4`

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think it's fair to say: please don't rely on null for standard operations. You'll get away with it in JS but it's really bad practice.

Comment: I totally agree, it is strictly a non type bound language pitfall or advantage depending on how you look at it.

Comment: Yeah, it likely depends on where you start. If you get to JS from a more structured language, it's terrifying to think of using it that way. If you started with JS, you'd reach a structured language and wonder why you can't do all the useful things!

Comment: While `false == 0` with the non-strict equality, neither `false` nor `0` are equal to `null`. Have you tried this?

Comment: The link seems to be broken.