# Why is output of variable NaN

Tags: javascript, function, variables, nan

I wrote simple code like this

```
var value = function(a){return a*3;}
var number = value(a);
```

when i type `value(5);` i will get number 15 thats OK, but after typing `number;` ill get `NaN`.
I just want to write in variable the result of function.

Comment: Sorry, it's kinda unclear. So it works as expected. Where do you want to write the number? Any sample use case?

Comment: Is it because your passing `a` as an argument `var number = value(a);` and `a` doesn't hold a number?

Comment: For a code like this: `var value = function(a) {
  return a * 3;
}
var number = value(5);
console.log(number);` I get `15` Not sure what you mean by your question.

Comment: It looks like `a` wasn't set to any value when you defined `number = value(a)`. So `value(a)` returned NaN and so that's what `number` was set to.

Comment: The `a` is local to the scope of the `value` function. You cannot use it outside the function.

Comment: yes you are right it works like this  .....`var number = value (5);` `console.log('result is ' + number);` in my value its alwas need to be only number which i want work with.

Comment: What you *should* be getting, if you don't have something like `var a;` earlier in your code, is a `ReferenceError: a is not defined` exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript is not a [computer algebra system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system), and it cannot store an algebraic expression like `x * 3` in a variable.  Instead, when you do:

```
var y = x * 3;
```

the variable `y` will be set to 3 times the value that `x` had *when that statement was executed*.  If no value has been assigned to `x` before, then its default value will be `undefined`.  And according to [JavaScript's arithmetic rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001320/is-null-considered-zero-and-undefined-not-a-number-on-arithmetic-expressions) `undefined` is automatically converted to `NaN` when used in an arithmetic expression, and `NaN * 3` equals `NaN`.

(Actually, what you *should* be getting, if you try to execute the code above without declaring the variable `x` first, is a `ReferenceError: x is not defined` exception.  But if you add a `var x;` statement before that code, to declare the variable `x` but leave its value undefined, then you'll indeed get `NaN` as the value of `y`.)

The fact that you've wrapped the multiplication inside a function makes no difference here.  The following code:

```
var f = function (a) { return a * 3 };
var y = f(x);
```

does exactly the same thing as:

```
var y = x * 3;
```

(except, of course, for the fact that the former version also defines the function `f`.)