# function accepts one argument either object or null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario where function only gets one argument which could be either `object` or  `null`. As both object and null has type of `object`. How can I use if statement on them to differentiate? If I use `typeof` then both object and null will return object.

**UPDATE**

```
function func (par) {
    if (par === null) {
        console.log(null);
    }

    if (typeof par === "object") {
        console.log(object);
    }
}

func({key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'});
func(null);
```

Comment: Does `=== null` not work?

Comment: I don't understand the problem. You're checking for null value and then you're checking the type to see if it's an object. Isn't that what you intended to do?

Comment: null is not an object, it is a primitive value. check this page :
[link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined

Comment: @AlexFord No because the second condition is true for both `object` and `null`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just check if the argument is null:

**UPDATED** (per change in problem definition)

`if(arg === null)`

```
function func (par) {
    if (par === null) {
        console.log(null);
    } else if(typeof par === "object") {
        console.log(par);
    } else {
        console.log("Unexpected parameter");
    }
}

func({width: '1px', color: 'orange'});
func(null);
```

Comment: You've added `object`, not sure where that variable came from

Comment: The problem with this is that the second if condition will be true for both `object` par and `null` par. That is what I don't want.

Comment: Then use `else` instead of 2 `if`s, updating my example

Comment: Is there a better solution rather than using several if else if.

Comment: Better solution to what? You asked how to check if something was null. Really, you don't need an else if, just an else.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know if it is `null` ***OR*** of type object then simply make the second `if` an `else if`.

```
function func (par) {
    if (par === null) {
        console.log(null);
    } else if (typeof par === "object") {
        console.log(object);
    }
}

func({key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2'});
func(null);
```

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/GbKeg

Comment: Is there any other solution? I mean better one.

Comment: lol, what does that even mean? Better how? If you *have* to know that `par` is an object then there is no better way to check that. If you don't *have* to know what the type is after you know it's not `null` then you can just use a simple `else` instead of `else if`. Other than that I don't know what else to tell you.