# What does 'if(newcontact.id == null)' mean?

Tags: angularjs, null

I am new to programming and am trying to learn angularJS to build a web app.  I came across an example contacts manager app and am having difficulty understanding part of it, namely the part that checks if a contact exists or not:

```
 if($scope.newcontact.id == null)
```

Ok, I get that this checks if this is a new contact, but I don't understand what is happening in logical terms.  I read up on `null` and understand it to mean that the thing being evaluated is known to exist, but does not have value.

So does this mean 'newcontact.id exists but does not have a value'?

Below is the javascript part of the app:

```
var uid = 1;

function ContactController($scope) {

$scope.contacts = [
    { id:0, 'name': 'Viral', 
      'email':'hello@gmail.com', 
      'phone': '123-2343-44'
    }
];

$scope.saveContact = function() {

    if($scope.newcontact.id == null) {
    //if this is new contact, add it in contacts array
    $scope.newcontact.id = uid++;
    $scope.contacts.push($scope.newcontact);
    } else {
    //for existing contact, find this contact using id
    //and update it.
    for(i in $scope.contacts) {
        if($scope.contacts[i].id == $scope.newcontact.id) {
        $scope.contacts[i] = $scope.newcontact;
        }
    }                
    }

    //clear the add contact form
    $scope.newcontact = {};
}


$scope.delete = function(id) {

    //search contact with given id and delete it
    for(i in $scope.contacts) {
        if($scope.contacts[i].id == id) {
            $scope.contacts.splice(i,1);
            $scope.newcontact = {};
        }
    }

}


$scope.edit = function(id) {
//search contact with given id and update it
    for(i in $scope.contacts) {
        if($scope.contacts[i].id == id) {
            //we use angular.copy() method to create 
            //copy of original object
            $scope.newcontact = angular.copy($scope.contacts[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if ($scope.newcontact.id == null)
```

if `$scope` exists AND `$scope` has a property called `newcontact` which also exists AND `newcontact` has a property called `id` AND `id` has not been assigned a value.

By that statement the author assumes (or has previously checked) that `$scope` exists and is not null and that `$scope.newcontact` exists and is not null. The explicit check is that `id` is a property on `newcontact` that has not been assigned a value.