# JPQL difference between "IS EMPTY" and "IS NULL"

Tags: jpql, isnull, is-empty

What is the difference between `IS EMPTY` and `IS NULL` in JPQL?

Is it about empty strings or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[IS NULL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_null) is used for NULL comparison.  [IS EMPTY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/apirefs.1111/e13946/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_empty_comp) is used for collection comparison.

What you probably want to know is the difference between NULL and empty string.  Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined).