# Is it safe to use comparison "if(foo)" instead of "if(foo == null)" on non-primitive types in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Assuming the foo is declared as a non-primitive type variable, but might be uninitialized, is there any possibility to use on non-primitive object comparison as this:

```
if (foo) {
...
}
```

or is it better to do it the longer way like this?

```
// not using "===" here on purpose, because the variable is non-primitive, so the value can't be 0 or empty string
if (foo != null) {
...
}
```

If it is not equal, then why.

Comment: Assuming `foo` is an object, `if(foo)` will pass for any object.

Comment: Man, `null` is primitive. The test will always pass under your assumption.

Comment: Check out [Truthy & Falsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/).

Comment: Yes, it is, but I'm talking about the variable, not about the null. If the variable is not initialized, I need to find it out and so I make a comparison to null.

Comment: This is the exact opposite, I guess you meant if (foo != null)

Comment: If you want to find out if a var is not initialized you should better use != undefined instead of != null

Comment: @Andree If a variable is not defined then it is `undefined` which again **is** primitive. You need to understand what you are talking about and be precise.

Comment: @treeno: Those are functionally identical.

Comment: @AdamSinclair Yes, sorry. Corrected.

Comment: @cookie mosnter undefined and null are fucntionally identical? what do you mean by that? I thought there would be a distinct difference. UNdefined means, that var itself does not exist. null means the var exists but it has no value

Comment: @freakish Ok, but I need to find out, if it is initialized. Considering it as initialized, it is non-primitive, if it isn't of course it is primitive.

Comment: @treeno: when you compare using `==` or `!=`, the comparison to `null` and `undefined` behave identically. They will always come up with the same result.

Comment: ...and `undefined` doesn't mean the var doesn't exist. If it doesn't exist, you'll get a ReferenceError when trying to read it.

Comment: @cookie monster because of type coercion?

Comment: @cookie monster what does it mean then?

Comment: What exactly does *"not initalized"* mean, is it declared ?

Comment: @treeno: Yes, using the Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm, which is what those operators use, the values of `null` and `undefined` are effectively the same. They compare to each other as well. `null == undefined; // true`

Comment: ...people think of `undefined` as meaning "existing but not initialized", and they think of `null` as meaning "has been set to an empty value". These are conventions. I think if they did it again, the language wouldn't have both values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "non-primitive type" you mean object? Yes, all objects are truthy, so it is enough to distinguish them via `if (foo)` from any falsy values that the `foo` variable might contain, such as the primitive values `undefined` and `null`.

However, notice that you cannot "declare a variable as a non-primitive type" in JavaScript, so you must ensure by other means that it never has a truthy primitive value. If you could ensure that it always contains an object, you wouldn't need the condition at all.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have found it to be safest to specify exactly what you want in boolean expressions and never rely on type coercion.

If you don't want it to be equal to 0 or null or empty string, then:

```
if (foo !== 0 && foo !== '' && foo !== null) {
  /* note that if foo = undefined, this will still get executed. */
}
```

Some libraries like `Underscore` or a framework like `Angular` have convenience functions for things like that, so you can do:

```
if (_.isObject(foo) === true) {
  /* execute this */
}
```