# Javascript confusing syntax inconsistence for null, instanceof and typeof?

Tags: javascript, oop, object, null

```
var obj = {};
typeof obj; // returns "object"
obj instanceof Object // return true

typeof null // returns "object"
null instanceof Object // returns false
```

And how about

```
typeof undefined // return "undefined"
undefined instanceof undefined 
// ERROR:  Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, 
//         but got undefined
```

Why is this the case? I have read a lot about related topics on SO but still can't get this.

Understand that 'typeof' would return a String, so it pretty much reflects the rules in Javascript.(eg. null is a object... well fine..) But why "null instanceof Object" return false ?

"x instanceof y"

Does it mean 'x' has to be created by the 'y' constructor? And for null this is not the case ?

**EDIT**

Would really appreciate if you could explain the different intention behind instanceof and typeof otherthan then syntax and return value.

*Difference between null and undefined*

```
typeof null        // object (bug in ECMAScript, should be null)
typeof undefined   // undefined
null === undefined // false
null  == undefined // true
```

**REF**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: The `typeof` operator is weird; there's not much else to it. However having `null` be an instance of Object would make very little sense, because a `null` reference clearly isn't an instance of *anything*.

Comment: `null` is just an exception to normal logic in this way.  I have idea why the JS designers made it this way, but this is how it is so we live with it.  for this reason, you often have to rule out `x !== null` before applying other tests.

Comment: @jfriend00 `I have idea why the JS designers made it this way` - Really? I am curious. What is the reason? I thought it was a mistake.

Comment: Is your question about `null` or `instanceof`?

Comment: @thefourtheye - sorry, I meant: "I have **no** idea why they made it that way".  Typo in my comment that can't be edited any more.

Comment: @thefourtheye it's about the instanceof and typeof and null, as show in the code. Sry would edit the title.

Comment: I agree that it's essentially a wart in the language design, but it's understandable that `typeof null` would end up being `object` because a `null` means that a variable or property is *not* a primitive value and also explicitly *not* referencing some object. The spec discusses a `Null` type, of which `null` is the only value, but the purpose of `null` as a value is to be a reference to no object. It's kind-of a conundrum, and I don't know how much better things would be if `typeof null` were `null`.

Answer (score 5):

It's just the design decision which might be contrived or weird. According to the `typeof` *UnaryExpression* if evaluated as the following. I've just included the poin that matters.

> [**ECMA Spec:**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)
>   Return a String determined by [`Type(val)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8) according to Table 20.

```
Table 20:
╔═════════════╦══════════╗
║ Type of val ║  Result  ║
╠═════════════╬══════════╣
║ null        ║ "object" ║
╚═════════════╩══════════╝
```

So, there's nothing we can do about it. It's [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design). But it's correct to return `false` because, there is a separate type for `null` called [`Null type`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.12)

> `Null type:`
>   type whose sole value is the null value

`null` isn't an instance of Object, obviously, since it has got it's own type. It's just that `typeof` operator returns `"object"`. It's got to do with the design of javascript.

Why is it so? Will have to ask Brendan Eich(Founder of Javascript).

Answer (score 0):

That's a common bug of ECMAScript.

`null` is not an `object`, it's a primitive value.(So you can't modify it like adding properties to it)

`typeof null` should return `null`

> typeof null        // object (bug in ECMAScript, should be null)
>
> typeof undefined   // undefined
>
> null === undefined // false
>
> null  == undefined // true

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

**EDITED**

It's not available to see though

> Changed 3 weeks ago by brendan
>
> You know, this all came about because
> of rushing in early May 1995, which led to a leak of type tag
> representation shared by null and object types. But null means "no
> object", so it didn't raise hackles until it was too late to fix in
> Netscape 2, and after that we were loath to "fix" it and "break the
> web". That argument only applies more in degree of web population now.
> We have other fish to fry. This one was has been swallowed already.
> Let's not change typeof null for ES4 and work on more vital issues.

http://web.archive.org/web/20071110193102/http://bugs.ecmascript.org/ticket/250

also check this answer

[Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined)

Comment: It's not a bug of ECMAScript, see the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

`instanceof` more appealing, however you checked `instaceof undefined` going throw exception that because the undefined is not any singular type object name, It's may or may not **`sub method`** of JavaScript `Object`. Because `undefined` that type for **`null`** (Null Type).

```
typeof undefined // return "undefined"
undefined instanceof Object // return False
```

You should check undefined is `instaceof` JS object, that give a no it's not the object. It's give a **`boolean`** result.