# Why null is an object in JavaScript, but null instanceof Object returns false?

Tags: javascript

Why `null` is an object in JavaScript, but `null instanceof Object` returns `false`? Is it because of the different constructors?

Comment: Do you have an example you would like us to take a look at in context?

Comment: Who said that? null is a primitive value in Javascript.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript confusing syntax inconsistence for null, instanceof and typeof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956060/javascript-confusing-syntax-inconsistence-for-null-instanceof-and-typeof)

Comment: The answer to "why" is always "because that's how the specification is written".

Comment: Related: [Why is typeof null “object”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18808226/why-is-typeof-null-object)

Answer (score 0):

`null` is not an object in JavaScript, it is a primitive type. There is a known  that `typeof null === 'object'` but still, `null` counts as a primitive and `instanceof` returns `false` for all primitives.

Comment: Not a bug, it was by design. See @Sudhir's comment.

Comment: It's not a bug. `typeof null` is defined to return "object". It would be a bug if an implementation returned anything other than "object".