# null object is an object in javascript so why is it not fixed?

Tags: javascript

In javaScript typeof null is an object is considered a bug. It should be null.
What is the reason why this is not fixed in the latest version of javascript?

Comment: Please provide more context and (preferably) references.

Comment: Marking duplicate doesn't take you to the intended answer, which is ref. zan: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7968470/1693593

Comment: What duplicate? I was not asking between the difference of null and undefined. Try to read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Null is not an object, its a primitive value.

Reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined?rq=1#answer-7968470) see `Axel Rauschmayer` answer

Comment: Try this : console.log(typeof null)