# Why is null an object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Is there some specific reason behind keeping null an object type in JavaScript? I have a lot of type-checking in my code and I would like to know the reason/explanation behind it, so I can clear out the confusion. Like

```
var bar = null;
console.log(typeof bar === "object");  // logs true!
```

In this case, what if bar was a function variable that returns an 'object'? Desired behaviour is that it should return true, but it actually return false.

```
var bar = function(){return {foo : 'bar'}};
console.log(typeof bar === "object");  // logs false!
```

Comment: At this point, it's probably not being changed for backwards compatibility reasons.  As for why it was originally done this way, you'd have to ask one of the original designers.

Comment: Mostly because NULL is a value.  It's not blank or zero.  It's NULL.  It is a valid testable value.

Comment: It is not object, it is [primitive](http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.2). This is just a preserved legacy bug in `typeof`.

Comment: `bar` is a function, you are not testing what it returns. so a function is not an object, hence false

Comment: Did you mean to do: `console.log(typeof bar() === "object");` where you actually execute `bar()` to check `typeof` the return value?

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined

Comment: @epascarello Correct! When I do typeof bar, it will not execute the function and get an object, it will just get function type. My bad!