# What is actually Null?

Tags: javascript, php, python, types, null

I don't know if I am asking a valid question or not, but I am curious why PHP, JavaScript, Python  interpret `null` differently

**Javascript :**

```
console.log(null === 0); // Outputs false
console.log(null + 1); //Outputs 1 , why ? if null isn't equal to zero
```

**PHP**

```
var_dump(null === 0);
// outputs boolean false

var_dump(null + 1);
// outputs int 1, why if null being not equals to zero ?
```

**Python :**

```
>>None == 0
>>false
```

Since python None is singleton object, so addition to its gives the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Curios about how other language interpret `NULL` ? And what it should be ?
And if `Null` isn't equals to `Zero` , why doing a addition on it , it behaves like `Zero` ?

Comment: To compare `null` in Javascript use `===`,  `null === 0`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is null an object and what's the difference between null and undefined?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined)

Comment: @Tushar right , but gives same result !

Comment: php and javascript are notorious for their "interesting" implementations of null.  Python's `None` is a singleton.

Comment: If you convert any non-numeric value to int (or any other numeric data type) will result in 0.

Comment: `var_dump(null === 0);` is false not true, `var_dump(null == 0);` is true

Comment: As of JS null + 1, JS ducktypedly autocast any value based on the operation, the parameters type, and their order as well.

Comment: @Jan.J sorry typo :(

Comment: Language design and divergent typecasting rules. Comparing NULL implementation and behaviour across multiple languages doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @mario out of curiosity , hope in SO we are allowed to ask such type of questions ? Or have to abide by strict rules & conventions?

Comment: A variable is NULL if it has no value, and points to nowhere in memory.

Comment: Higher level language design questions can still be on-topic, of couse. But this one is a bit too broad IMO, perhaps even misleading if someone googles for the wrong keywords.

Comment: @mario ok , will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2):

You can look at **type comparison tables** of each language to get some understanding. Here are tables for 3 languages you listed:

- [JS](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/)
- [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)
- [Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thmzF.png)

And then you should check how `null` (or `None`) are casted to other types.

For PHP:

- `(int)null` is `0`
- `(string)null` is `''` (empty string)

For JS:

- `null + 0` is `0`, `null + 1` is `1`, but `parseInt(null)` is `NaN`
- `null + ''` is `'null'` and `String(null)` is `'null'`

Can't check it for Python right now. But you see why it behaves like that in PHP and JS. The reasons behind this differences are probably more complicated.

Comment: Well buddy I wanted to know what we really consider NULL as ?

Comment: @n01ze then you'll probably have to explain what *"what we really consider NULL as ?"* actually means

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes u r totally correct, I agree with you on this