# Data not saved in the variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have this code

```
$scope.setContent = function (data) {
        if ($scope.unfiltered_tree == null) {
            $scope.unfiltered_tree = data;
        }
   }
```

the data saved in the unfiltered_tree for the first time,and when new data comes it's not saved.

Any help on that?

Comment: Have you console logged the inside of the if clause to verify that it is being triggered?

Comment: It's not saved because it's not null. Since it's not null the `if` statement fails and doesn't run

Comment: Remove the `if` statement, because your `$scope.unfiltered_tree` will be set only if it was `null`.

Comment: [take a look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/801032/why-is-null-an-object-and-whats-the-difference-between-null-and-undefined)

Comment: I check the console and it's triggered and because  it's not null it goes to it but it not saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand your question. Are you asking how to ALWAYS store the new data in your variable? Just remove the if statement.

```
$scope.setContent = function (data) {
        $scope.unfiltered_tree = data;
   }
```

The purpose of the if statement may have been to check if your variable has been intialized or not. In that case you may want to use the following format:

```
$scope.setContent = function (data) {
        if (!$scope.unfiltered_tree) {
            // Variable has not been initialized yet
            $scope.unfiltered_tree = data;
        } else {
            // Variable has been initialized before, do something else
          }
   }
```